# How can I give control back (briefly) to the browser during intensive JavaScript processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read the post [here](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/10/28/) about using setTimeout() during intensive DOM processing (using JavaScript), but how can I integrate this function with the below code? The below code works fine for a small number of options, but when the number of options gets too big my "please wait" animated GIF freezes while the local JavaScript is processing. Thanks!

```
function appendToSelect() {
    $("#mySelect").children().remove() ;
    $("#mySelect").html(
        '<option selected value="' + obj.data[0].value + '">'
        + obj.data[0].name
        + '</option>'
    );
    var j = 1 ;
    for (var i = 1; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
        $("#mySelect").append(
            '<option value="' + obj.data[i].value + '">'
            + obj.data[i].name
            + '</option>'
        ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: tell them to use Chrome and they will have JITted javascript :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
function appendToSelect() {
  $("#mySelect").children().remove();
  $("#mySelect").html(
    '<option selected value="'+obj.data[0].value+'">'
    + obj.data[0].name
    + '</option>'
  );
  obj.data.splice(0, 1); // we only want remaining data
  var appendOptions = function() {
    var dataChunk = obj.data.splice(0, 10); // configure this last number (the size of the 'chunk') to suit your needs
    for(var i = 0; i < dataChunk.length; i++) {
      $("#mySelect").append(
        '<option value="' + dataChunk[i].value + '">'
        + dataChunk[i].name
        + '</option>'
      );
    }
    if(obj.data.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(appendOptions, 100); // change time to suit needs
    }
  };
  appendOptions(); // kicks it off
}
```

Not as elegant as [@Borgar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/giving-brief-control-back-to-the-browser-during-intensive-javascript-processing#210968) solution, but you get the idea. Basically, I am doing the same thing, but all in your one function rather than breaking it into a higher-order function like he does. I like his solution, but if you don't, perhaps this will work for you.

---

EDIT: For those that don't immediately see it, one of the main differences between this solution and [@Borgar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/giving-brief-control-back-to-the-browser-during-intensive-javascript-processing#210968) is that this solution allows you to set the size of the 'chunks' of data that is processed between each timeout. [@Borgar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/giving-brief-control-back-to-the-browser-during-intensive-javascript-processing#210968) times-out after *every single member* of the array is processed. If I get time, I will try to create a higher-order function to handle this so it is more elegant. No promises though! ;)

---

EDIT: So, here is my adaptation of [@Borgar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/giving-brief-control-back-to-the-browser-during-intensive-javascript-processing#210968) solution, which allows for setting a 'chunk' size and configuring the timeout value more easily:

```
function incrementallyProcess(workerCallback, data, chunkSize, timeout, completionCallback) {
  var itemIndex = 0;
  (function() {
    var remainingDataLength = (data.length - itemIndex);
    var currentChunkSize = (remainingDataLength >= chunkSize) ? chunkSize : remainingDataLength;
    if(itemIndex < data.length) {
      while(currentChunkSize--) {
        workerCallback(data[itemIndex++]);
      }
      setTimeout(arguments.callee, timeout);
    } else if(completionCallback) {
      completionCallback();
    }
  })();
}

function appendToSelect() {
  $("#mySelect").children().remove();
  $("#mySelect").html(
    '<option selected value="' + obj.data[0].value + '">'
    + obj.data[0].name
    + '</option>'
  );
  obj.data.splice(0,1); // we only want remaining data      
  incrementallyProcess(function(data) {
    $("#mySelect").append(
    '<option value="' + data.value + '">'
    + data.name
    + '</option>'
   );
  }, obj.data, 10, 100, removeAnimatedGifFunction); // last function not required...
}
```

Hope that helps - I think this combines the best of both solutions. **Notice**, the second anonymous function no longer uses the index value, but simply passes in the entire object (with the value and name properties); that makes it a bit cleaner, since the index of the current object really isn't *usually* that useful when iterating over things, IMO.

I am sure there are still things that could be done to make this even better, but that is left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Answer (score 20):

It just so happens that I was posting about this a moment ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205631/javascript-loadingbusy-indicator-or-transparent-div-over-page-on-event-click#210931). Here is a timed loop function:

```
function processLoop( actionFunc, numTimes, doneFunc ) {
  var i = 0;
  var f = function () {
    if (i < numTimes) {
      actionFunc( i++ );  // closure on i
      setTimeout( f, 10 )
    } 
    else if (doneFunc) { 
      doneFunc();
    }
  };
  f();
}
```

For your situation this would be used like this:

```
function appendToSelect () {

  $("#mySelect").children().remove() ;
  $("#mySelect").html(
      '<option selected value="' + obj.data[0].value + '">'
      + obj.data[0].name
      + '</option>'
  );
  var j = 1 ;

  processLoop(function (i){
    $("#mySelect").append(
        '<option value="' + obj.data[i].value + '">'
        + obj.data[i].name
        + '</option>'
    ); 
  }, obj.data.length);

}
```

You'll want to make sure that you have a closure or some other access to the obj variable within the iteration function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you need something simpler, I wrote a jQuery plugin to ease writing of asynchronous loops: [jQuery Async](http://mess.genezys.net/jquery/jquery.async.php).

Using the plugin, your code can be rewritten as:

```
function appendToSelect() {
    $("#mySelect").children().remove() ;
    $("#mySelect").html(
        '<option selected value="' + obj.data[0].value + '">'
        + obj.data[0].name
        + '</option>'
    );

    /////////////////////////////
    var i = 1;
    $.whileAsync({
        test: function(){ i < obj.data.length; }
        loop: function()
        {
            $("#mySelect").append(
                '<option value="' + obj.data[i].value + '">'
                + obj.data[i].name
                + '</option>'
            ); 
            i++;
        }
    });
    /////////////////////////////
}
```

Should help the responsiveness. Tweak the 'bulk' and 'delay' option for more control.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to rewrite the function to cache the element list, then loop over the list using a counter of some sort.

Then when the counter reaches counter % max_num_before_wait == 0, call timeout back to the function itself.

Make sure to clear the cache and counter at the end of the complete list, or use a secondary function with an extra count parameter.