# Javascript: Lazy Load Images In Horizontal Div?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, lazy-loading

I have a div that has a bunch of thumbnails showing horizontally (with a horizontal scrollbar). Is there a way to lazy load these thumbnails and only show them once the user horizontally scrolls to their position? All the examples I've seen check the browser window, not a div.

This is for contest entries so sometimes there are hundreds of entries, which drastically affects performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>I forked the [lazy load plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazyload) for jQuery and added support for lazy-loading images in a container div.</del> The [lazy load plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazyload) for jQuery now supports this directly. It shouldn't be too hard to remove the dependency on jQuery or adapt it to another library if you need to.

<del>You can get my forked project from github: http://github.com/silentmatt/jquery_lazyload/tree/master.</del>

To use it, call lazyload on the images just like in the original, except you need to add a "container" option with the scrolling div element. So if your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 765px; overflow: scroll;">
    <img src="image1.jpg" width="765" height="574">
    <img src="image2.jpg" width="765" height="574">
    <img src="image3.jpg" width="765" height="574">
    ...
</div>
```

you would call lazyload like this:

```
$("#container img").lazyload({ container: $("#container") });
```

Comment: thanks so much! I've been pulling my hair out for this for a long time!

Comment: Quick question: it doesn't seem to work in IE, is that a known issue?

Comment: I think the problem was the load event not firing when the images loaded too fast. I changed it so it sets the src attribute after binding the to load event, so it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

See my question where I encountered a similar problem. [Jason Bunting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790/jason-bunting) gave me a handy little script to load images in chunks.:

[How to display loading status with preloader and multiple images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334325/how-to-display-loading-status-with-preloader-and-multiple-images)