# Lazy Load horizontal scroll jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein, horizontal-scrolling, lazy-loading

So, I'm working on this photography portfolio website for a client who really wants her photographs to fade in as they appear in the browser window. So I did some research and it seemed like the jquery plugin `lazyload` would be perfect. The problem is that she also really wants her photographs to be on a horizontal scroll and it seems like `lazyload` only wants to work on vertically scrolling webpages. I searched around and apparently `lazyload` is supposed to work in side scrolling divs with this script:

```
 $("img").lazyload({
     container: $("#container")
 });
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Currently this is what my code looks like:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {          
$("#content img.fadeload").lazyload({
    container: $("#content"),
    placeholder : "images/white.jpg",
    effect      : "fadeIn",
    effectspeed: 1000 
});
});
</script>
<style>
#content {
font-size: 100%;
position: absolute;
height: 574px;
width: 750px;
margin-top: -277px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 240px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
top: 50%;
overflow-x: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo01.jpg" alt="photo01"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo02.jpg" alt="photo02"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo03.jpg" alt="photo03"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo04.jpg" alt="photo04"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo05.jpg" alt="photo05"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo06.jpg" alt="photo06"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo07.jpg" alt="photo07"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo08.jpg" alt="photo08"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo09.jpg" alt="photo09"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo10.jpg" alt="photo10"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo11.jpg" alt="photo11"/>
    <img class="fadeload" src="images/white.jpg" data-original="images/liveStuffHotStuff/photo12.jpg" alt="photo12"/>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is a [temporary link to the website in progress](http://thefuhrl.com/jennaSpitz/album01.html) if you want to see the functionality (or lack of functionality rather) of the `lazyload` plugin in its current state.

Any advice relating to getting lazyload to function the way I want it to or a recommendation of another method altogether for an image fadein effect would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Comment: may be this will help you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444730/javascript-lazy-load-images-in-horizontal-div

Comment: oh yea, i meant to add that i did see that stackoverflow entry and it did not work for me. That and this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_wide_container.html are the only two resources I could find on getting lazyload to work horizontally and neither of them seemed to change anything.

Comment: You mean the wide container demo page does not work for you? Which browser?

Comment: The demo works in firefox, but not chrome, I haven't tested other browsers yet. But as far as I can tell the code from the demo is not working as applied to the website I'm trying to put it on in either chrome nor firefox. Also, as a side note, I would rather have the div that contains the images have no width attribute and instead have the scroll bar be at the bottom of the browser rather than the bottom of the div. like this: http://thefuhrl.com/jennaSpitz2/album01.html

Comment: Which version of chrome? I do not have problems with latest Windows nor OSX chrome. What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are missing width and height attributes. Lazy Load wont work properly without them. Without knowing width and height browser cannot know where images are supposed to be in the layout when `document.ready` event fires. Proper image tag looks something like following:

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"  width="640" heigh="480">
```

Comment: Just remove the container paramater. Just the same ways as in demo page: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_wide.html

If the answer fixed the problem mark it as accepted.

Comment: Adding hight and width properties to the images worked! Now if I wanted to do "overflow: hidden;" and omit a width attribute on the div so that the horizontal scroll bar would be on the browser window is there a way to get lazyload to work in that situation? like instead of adding the script ({ container: $("#content"), }) it was something like ({ container: $("body") }) maybe? Here's an example of the situation I'm talking about: thefuhrl.com/jennaSpitz2/album01.html

Comment: Ahhh, I never came across the page for the "wide" demo somehow. Thanks a ton! You're awesome!

Comment: So its working great on computers, although a bit laggy on Firefox for some reason. But on mobile devices its crazy laggy. It takes 10 seconds or more sometimes before an image starts to fade in. Is there an easy way to optimize lazy load for mobile? and if not is there a way to turn lazy load off when being visited by ios, android, or other mobile operating systems?

Here is the current incarnation of the website using lazy load that is having trouble on mobile devices: http://thefuhrl.com/jennaSpitz/album01.html

Comment: It starts to fade in after browser has loaded the image. Your mobile connection is most likely slower than your desktop connection.

Comment: Yea, I thought that was probably the case. What do you recommend is the best way to turn lazy load off for mobile devices? I made a new stack overflow question on the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914900/disable-lazy-load-for-mobile-devices