# How to avoid the Unresponsive Script popup in Firefox with long running Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to benchmark some Javascript code in the browser, but it may trigger Firefox's "Warning: Unresponsive script" popup.  This allows the user to click "Stop script" in the event that the browser is caught in a runaway function.  While the pop-up is displayed, the currently running function has been halted.  This isn't ideal, so is there a way to run my benchmarks differently such that Firefox doesn't popup this warning and ruin my results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In firefox's address bar type about:config

You want to change dom.max_script_run_time to be large enough for your scripts to run.

Comment: Is he supposed to do that for every user of the page?

Comment: He's using it for benchmarking--I don't think there are other users.

Answer (score 9):

You have to break up long actions into smaller ones and perform them in turns. This will also allow a better progress indication.

http://www.sonofsofaman.com/hobbies/code/settimeout.asp

Comment: Can you elaborate?  A simple example, maybe?

Comment: Here's an example of using setTimeout to break up the running of the javascript: http://www.sonofsofaman.com/hobbies/code/settimeout.asp

If you're doing benchmarks, make sure that you allow the code to run long enough to make up for the timer resolution. You'll probably want to read this: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: That link seems to be broken. Could you elaborate on how to do that in your answer?

Answer (score 4):

See in blog of Nicholas C. Zakas
What determines that a script is long-running? (at 2009/01/05)

Speed up your JavaScript, Part 1
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/

there are the reasons and the ways how to avoid the dialog

Answer (score 2):

You can use the script from this question to break processing long lists into smaller chunks:

[How can I give control back (briefly) to the browser during intensive JavaScript processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/#210994)

Answer (score 0):

The below code solved that problem for me...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function downloadJSAtOnload() {
   var element = document.createElement("script");
   element.src = "deferredfunctions.js";
   document.body.appendChild(element);
   }
   if (window.addEventListener)
   window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
   else if (window.attachEvent)
   window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
   else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```