# Unresponsive script - is it possible to avoid it?

Tags: jquery

I have a listing with 150 rows and for each row there are three skinned select items.

Because there's heavy processing to be done before displaying each result I get an error saying "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete." and it refers to jquery.js file.

Is it possible to avoid this error by doing some jQuery work?

Thank you.

Comment: can't really tell without you showing us any snippet :S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917380/how-to-avoid-the-unresponsive-script-popup-in-firefox-with-long-running-javascri

Answer (score 6):

You need to split your processing into multiple parts and give the browser some time to *do stuff* besides them by using a 0 or 1 msec setTimeout.

A very easy method would be using the [`forEachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachseriesarr-iterator-callback) method of the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library:

```
async.forEachSeries(yourData, function(item, cb) {
    // process item
    async.nextTick(cb);
});
```

`yourData` could be the jQuery object containing your rows, then `item` will be the DOM element of one row.

Comment: is `0 or 1 msec setTimeout` enough?

Comment: yes it is, because tasks that are waiting will get executed at the moment the script stops. JavaScript is single threaded so the execution will actually not start before the newly started code has finished. So the duration does not really matter

Comment: So I need to add this timeout in the JS, not in the PHP, right?

Comment: Yes, this is a client-side thing.

Comment: Oh, but I don't have a loop or something in JS. I'm using JS just to skin that select item. All the processing is done in PHP.

Comment: Check out my asnwer. It has a link to a page where this technique is described

Comment: There has top be a javascript that is doing a lot of work otherwise you would not see the message you described. Are you perhaps doing ajax using synchronous calls? That will block the UI as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery (if there is some wrapper available in jQuery), but in vanilla JS there is the concept of WebWorkers (support is rather good except for IE - see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=webworker)).

Here you start an extra thread to to you computations, that does not block your UI thread. When the computations are done and just the result display is left over, you send the data from the worker to the UI thread and just display the results.

For details, have a look at the [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers).

Answer (score 0):

> Download JavaScript as and when required, instead of downloading it
>   all on page load.

[On Demand JavaScript](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Website performance guru Steve Souders wrote about this problem and how to solve it in his book "Even faster web sites". He describes a solution where you use timeouts to let other processes get some time as well.

[Here's](http://books.google.nl/books?id=E7p-07kNfXYC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=avoid%20long%20running%20scripts%20souders&source=bl&ots=UMenRKgdRp&sig=bGLYgeFHZyLmDq9NbUpXbNgGou8&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=kKq8T7mgAqbB0QXPo5hB&ved=0CFYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) the part of the book that deals with this problems.