# Script becoming unresponsive in jquery,jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid in my project.I'm displaying over 2000 rows of data with 15 rows on each page of the jqGrid. I encountered the problem while selecting all the elements or deselecting all the elements or when trying to navigate to last page.

The problem is that in Firefox im getting unresponsive script warning dialog when trying to do  any of the above mentioned operations.

Code works fine when im dealing with couple of hundereds of lines.When i go above 1000 the problems kicks in.

Is there any way to avoid this? or any workaround? Can i put the loading dialog in the front when the operations is carried out in the back just like we do in mobile,something on this lines.

Comment: Is the issue with jqGrid or your database access? Check out your browser development tools to see what is taking the time. It could be that you may need to add indexes to your DB or prevent huge amounts of data being pulled down in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the response.This is after all the data is loaded.When have a "loading" dialog when we are initially loading all the data.The problem is not that.Its occurs afterwards when we try to navigate through the data using pager and when we perform actions like select all deselect all.thanks

Comment: P.S. The data is loaded only once.We are not loading data again and again in the grid so thats not the case.

Comment: Is the problem only contained to Firefox?

Comment: not only firefox its slow is all browser.But only firefox and ie8 is showing that dialog.thanks

Comment: Have a look here, might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917380/how-to-avoid-the-unresponsive-script-popup-in-firefox-with-long-running-javascri