# How often does the timeupdate event fire for an html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

Learning html5 stuff. It's pretty awesome! Wondering how often the timeupdate event fires.

SIDE NOTE: There are so many interesting possibilities with the js video api. For instance, it might be possible to use ctrl + F to search through video. Run a voice recognition as part of video processing, then create a long key value store with timestamps as keys and words as values, and write a function that searches for instances of those words, but returns timestamps and seeks your video. Anyways, that's just one crazy idea youtube should jump on.

Any help with timeupdate would be awesome!

Comment: Hey, this word search is a pretty cool idea!

Comment: Know anyone that works at Vimeo or YouTube who might implement it?

Comment: Nope. It will have its own chalenges. It is trivial to index the video if it has subtitles, but if it hasn't, then server has to automate speech to text. Since it own't always be a 5-10 second video, may be around 10 minutes long or so, the process has to convert a substantially long audio to text, which itself is difficult, accuracy aside.

Comment: Sounds right to me. What do you think, worthy challenges, or not worth it?

Comment: Worthy, definitely.. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [this Bugzilla page](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571822):

> Firefox fires the timeupdate event once per frame. Safari 5 and Chrome 6 fire every 250ms.  Opera 10.50 fires every 200ms.

Comment: Go Firefox btw, that makes so much sense to do it once per frame.

Comment: Unless your binding some kind of callback; firing a callback 25 times a second can be quite intensive... particularly when you can't throttle it.

Comment: How else might you let a program know to execute a function at a particular moment of a video?

Comment: see my answer if it helps!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460263/disabling-the-long-running-script-message-in-internet-explorer/31390750#31390750

Answer (score 3):

I used a generic throttle function

```
_self.throttle = function (fn, threshhold, scope) {
    threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
    var last,
        deferTimer;
    return function () {
        var context = scope || this;

        var now = +new Date,
            args = arguments;
        if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
            // hold on to it
            clearTimeout(deferTimer);
            deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                last = now;
                fn.apply(context, args);
            }, threshhold);
        } else {
            last = now;
            fn.apply(context, args);
        }
    };
};
```

and wired it up with

```
myPlayer.on('timeupdate', window.vm.throttle(function () {
        window.vm.setWatched(myPlayer.currentTime());
    }, 3000));
```

hope this helps someone.

code cribbed from http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/

Comment: Does the myPlayer = document.querySelector('audio') ? Since the Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLAudioElement> has no method 'on'

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to run a function every so often it'd be a better idea to run it using the play and pause events.

Below is an example of running a process every 3 seconds while the video is playing.

```
video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  video._updateInterval = setInterval(() => {
    // do what you need
  }, 3000);
}, true);

video.addEventListener('pause', () => clearInterval(video._updateInterval), true);
```