# scroll when specific time reaches in video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, scroll, html5-video

I am developing a page in which i have to show video with its related pdf.
I have used pdf.js and video.js projects for reading pdf and video respectively.
They both are implemented in different div. this is the link of my page's screenshot [here](http://i1069.photobucket.com/albums/u463/hiteshtr/Screenshot-33-1.png) .I need to implement a function which checks for video current time and change the position of the pdf div according to time
below is the code i implemented but its not working at all

```
//function to perform on every timeupdate
var myFunc =function(){
    var myPlayer = this;
    var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
//working of function
switch(whereYouAt)
{
    case 30: bookmarkscroll('pageContainer2');
         break;
    case 60: bookmarkscroll('pageContainer3');
         break;
    case 90: bookmarkscroll('pageContainer4');
         break;
    case 120: bookmarkscroll('pageContainer5');
          break;
    case 150: bookmarkscroll('pageContainer6');
          break;
    case 180: bookmarkscroll('pageContainer7');
          break;

}

};
myPlayer.addEvent("timeupdate",myFunc);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `timeupdate` event does not care about nice looking decimal numbers and might fire at any given time and even at **[different intervals depending on your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678177/how-often-does-the-timeupdate-event-fire-for-an-html5-video)** (therefore return something like `12.56661`) you should change your handling of the value that `currentTime` (which is also a property and not a method - therefore no `()` - see **[this doc](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)**) returns.

Something like this should work:

```
//select video player only once
var myPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');

//function to perform on every timeupdate
var myFunc =function(){

var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime; 

if (whereYouAt > 30 && whereYouAt <= 60){
   bookmarkscroll('pageContainer2');
} else if (whereYouAt > 60 && whereYouAt <= 90){
   bookmarkscroll('pageContainer3');
} else if .... //and so on

}

myPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate',myFunc,false);
```

Another thing to note is that the method for attaching event listeners is called **[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)** and not `addEvent`

Comment: its not scrolling may be becoz all the code of both pdf and video are in different divs

Comment: @hiteshtr If the video events behave properly and the scrolling's not working then why don't you try to break that down and ask a new question about the issue? Also do sth simple like `console.log('trying to bookmarkscroll');` right before you call the `bookmarkscroll` to see if the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

that's because timeupdate isn't usually 1,2,3,4, it s sth like 1.02302350,1.12412312. so you switch case will never get the right time. try using intervalls like

```
this.currentPageContainer; //save your current container


if( whereYouAt > 30 && whereYouAt < 60 ){
  var scrollTo = 'pageContainer2';
  if( this.currentPageContainer == scrollTo ) return;  //break, if already scrolled

  bookmarkscroll('pageContainer2');
  this.currentPageContainer = scrollTo;
}
else if( whereYouAt > 60 && whereYouAt < 90  ) ...
```

don t know if you really need the break, because i don t know your scrollfunction. best l

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.floor` on your `currentTime` like so:

```
var whereYouAt = Math.floor(myPlayer.currentTime);
```

This will return an `integer` and your `switch` statement will work.