# HTML5's Video, Getting Each And Every Frame

Tags: html, video, canvas, frame, capture

I want to get ALL the frames off a video element, show each of them on a canvas. (not miss a single frame).

I've found out I can use:

```
videoPlayer.currentTime = i; // (i = 0...video-size)
```

and than save each from with:

```
contextVideo.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, canvasVideo.width, canvasVideo.height);
```

But this causes only round-seconds frames to be saved, and I want all of them.

How can this be done ?

Is there a way to

```
currentTime = milliseconds;
```

?

Comment: May be this will help [Get frame change in video HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044567/get-frame-change-in-video-html5).

Comment: Seen it already, it doesn't provide a solution for all the frames, but only some of them, depends on the system's speed.

Comment: no time to provide details, but watch out for the progress event of the video. (the provided link to S.O. is... so-so :-) )