# How can I fire only once for each comment in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made animation in which, all the loaded comments appears and disappear when next comment comes.

I made [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/) so please, check it!

The problem is that `timeupdate` is working about 10 times per second.
So animation is being fired for 10 times for every comment:(
Please see DEMO, and you'll notice that it looks weird move.

How can I handle that?
Can anyone modify my code in JSfiddle, please.

These are my code.

**javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#video').on('timeupdate',function(e){
            showComments(this.currentTime);  
    });

}); 
var comments = [{'time':'10','message':'hello! 10 secs has past'},{'time':'15','message':'hello! 15 secs has past'},{'time':'5','message':'hello! 5 secs has past'},{'time':'20','message':'hello! 20 secs has past'}];


function showComments(time){
    var comments = findComments(time);
    $.each(comments,function(i,comment){
        $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"400px","opacity":".0"}, 600).fadeOut(100);
        $('.newsticker').append("<p style='margin-left:400px;opacity:0'>"+comment.message+"</p>");
        $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);
    });
}

function findComments(time){
    return $.grep(comments, function(item){
      return item.time == time.toFixed();
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="newsticker"> 
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media"><source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}

.newsticker p{
    height:20px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: I'll up you one: the firing interval for timeupdated depends on the browser. In chrome it's about every 250ms, in FF it's for every frame. Isn't it better to mark a comment as displayed once you display it and change findComments so it won't find displayed comments?

Comment: Oooh, to busy watching the totally irrelevant video to actually change any code !

Comment: @MrP Something like `if(comments != last_comments){ transaction; last_comments = comments;}`?

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678177/how-often-does-the-timeupdate-event-fire-for-an-html5-video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Add a shown flag into the comments, and check for that, update where appropriate.</strike>

Note, I've also renamed some local variables to prevent clashes with parent scope ones (doesn't impact the code, but firebug got a bit funny about showing me the correct thing)

**Updated**

Converted it into a jquery plugin, for cleanliness, also put the check around the time as @BMH's answer (so feel free to mark his as the accepted). Stopped it showing all the comments for a timestamp if there's more than one, and will re-show a comment if re-wound to a previous time:

http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/12/

```
jQuery.fn.videoComments = function(options){
    var defaults = {
        "comments" : [
            {'time':'10','message':'hello! 10 secs has past'},
            {'time':'15','message':'hello! 15 secs has past'},
            {'time':'5','message':'hello! 5 secs has past'},
            {'time':'20','message':'hello! 20 secs has past'}
        ],
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    if(!options.commentHolder){
        throw "videoComments requires a commentHolder to put the comments in";
    }

    function setComment(message){
            $commentContainer.css({
                "marginLeft" : "400px",
                "opacity": "0"
            }).html(message);
    };

    var $commentContainer = $("<p></p>");
    setComment("");

    $(options.commentHolder).append($commentContainer);

    function showComments(time){
        var foundComments = findComments(time);
        $.each(foundComments,function(i,comment){
            $commentContainer.animate({"marginLeft":"400px","opacity":".0"}, 600);
            setComment(comment.message);
            $commentContainer.animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);
        });
    };

    function findComments(timeToFind){
        var matchingComments = $.grep(options.comments, function(item){
          return (item.time == timeToFind);
        });

        return matchingComments;
    };

    return $(this).each(function(){
        var currentTime = -1;
        $(this).on("timeupdate", function(e) {
            var localTime = this.currentTime.toFixed();
            if(currentTime != localTime){
                currentTime = localTime;
                showComments(currentTime); 
            }
        });
    });
};

$("#video").videoComments({
    "commentHolder" : $(".newsticker")    
})
```

Comment: Hey but what if a user rewind the video? the comments that are already shown won't appear anymore. Please cover this problem!

Comment: True, okay, I'll tweak

Comment: @Psytronic what if calling from jwplayer onTime? `jwplayer("myElement").onTime(function(time){showComments(Math.round(time.position));})`

Comment: Can't say I've ever used jwplayer (or heard of it until now). I would think that you could do something like: `$(jwplayer("myElement")).videoComments(); jwplayer("myElement").onTime(function(time) { this.trigger("timeupdate"); });` ?

Comment: @Psytronic Your code made it perfect but one more thing. How can you show comment right in the middle of vertical align? For example, if the comment is too long, and and it becomes two lines, it looks kinda positioning in the middle of vertical align. But if it's one line, it looks that the comment is shown a little bit above than middle position. Can you fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I would put flag in the ready function:

http://jsfiddle.net/b_m_h/9zqhF/11/

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var fixedTime = 0;
    $('#video').on('timeupdate',function(e){
        if(this.currentTime.toFixed() != fixedTime){
            showComments(fixedTime);
            fixedTime = this.currentTime.toFixed()
        }  
    });

}); 
var comments = [{'time':'10','message':'hello! 10 secs has past'},{'time':'10','message':'hello! part-2 10 secs has past'},{'time':'15','message':'hello! 15 secs has past'},{'time':'5','message':'hello! 5 secs has past'},{'time':'20','message':'hello! 20 secs has past'}];


function showComments(time){
    var coms = findComments(time);
    if(coms[0]){
            $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"400px","opacity":".0"}, 600).fadeOut(100);
            $('.newsticker').append("<p style='margin-left:400px;opacity:0'>"+coms[0].message+"</p>");
            $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);
    }
}

function findComments(time){
    return $.grep(comments, function(item){
      return item.time == time;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. If there were two comments in 10 secs, it looks weird(Please check http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/6/)  How can you disable `part2` at 10 seconds? If there were more than 2 comments at the same second, I want to ignore second and all the comments after that.

Comment: So you only want the first comment for any given second?

Comment: @Psytronic Please check my demo on JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/6/  Do you see there are two comments at 10 seconds?  I want to ignore 2nd comment if there are more than 2 comments at the same second. I'd precede 1st comment to show.

Comment: if so you don't need to use `each` function. I have update my answer, just for reference.