# long-running-script message in Internet Explorer 8 - while doing lot of Asynchronous call in a page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

Am using **MVC4 with Jquery AJAX** in one of my web application. In one of the Web page(Huge Page) am getting usual "long-running-script message in Internet Explorer 8"

**What is happening in that web Page**

- We have around 60 Sections(Itz huge but thatz how our customer wants to see it..thinking of redesigning)
- Each section is loaded on demand(using Jquery AJAX,and all sections have lot of scripts execution)
- Inside few  sections we have subsection as well which is again loaded on Demand using AJAX

**Where i am getting the script Error ?**

if i open more sections like above (30) am getting the long running problem

Am opening sections one by one not parallely also `i.e` after one section is opened am moving to next section. if i go on like that am getting the problem when i click on 35th section "

**Is there a limit on number(Amount) of script Execution in IE ?**

i saw the limitation on  maximum number of synchronous instructions for a piece of JavaScript. The default maximum is 5,000,000. [Disabling the long-running-script message in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460263/disabling-the-long-running-script-message-in-internet-explorer)

Am not doing any synchronous instructions. is there any limit on Asynchronous at page level as well ?

I can redesign and split out my page but am curious to know is this a limitation in IE8. Your views are Welcome

*Mozilla and Chrome works fine