# How do you stop an infinite loop in javascript via memory?

Tags: javascript

I have a editor whereby users can input their javascript and it displays their output. But I want a safety condition to stop them being able to accidentally create an infinite loop. The issue is I really don't want to parse the code and look for any loops and then add extra conditions. What I'm hoping for is a prebuilt function that cancels itself after a certain amount of memory, to avoid the browser crashing. I am unsure how to do this however.

Comment: I think this one can help you: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/19/javascript-stack-overflow-error/

it explain what hapen when you create infinite loop and how to handle this (by browser)

Comment: @MrJedi That's pretty much irrelevant. `while(true) { }` will not raise an error you can handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com) runs an open source project named [`loop-protect`](https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect) you can use that, it's easy to implement.

[Codepen has article on that](http://blog.codepen.io/2014/10/29/preventing-infinite-loops-grid/)

Comment: Neat. I was unaware of loop-protect. Unfortunate that it doesn't handle recursion.

Comment: yeah, there is [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) JavaScript parser with help of that it's possible.

Comment: Seems less important for infinite recursion situations since the script will fail after only a moment with a too much recursion error, so it won't crash or freeze the browser.

Comment: The OP did say _"I really don't want to parse the code and look for any loops and then add extra conditions."_

Comment: OP is hoping for prebuilt function that stops after certain amount of memory, I don't think there's prebuilt like this in JS, so I just suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to do this *in JavaScript itself* because JavaScript in the browser is single-threaded.* If a "hostile" script never yields then your code won't get a chance to run – to kill the user's script.

In some cases the runtime can do this for you – Internet Explorer is notorious for [its obnoxious error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4460263/139010) but I'm not aware of any platform-agnostic way to request such protection from the environment.

---

<sub>* ignoring web workers, which are not relevant to the discussion since message handling occurs in the main "thread" anyway.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is probably to interpret the JavaScript. That's how http://repl.it does it ((http://repl.it/help).), and there's really nice feedback when you do infinite loops. `var f=function(){f();};f();` produces this output: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

JS-interpreter seems to be interpreting the JavaScript with Acorn JS, and you might be able to add detection for infinite loops: https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter

Another option is to use Web Workers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage):

- Move the users' scripts into Web workers using something on the server side. You could also use data URIs like in this MDN example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Advanced_concepts_and_examples. However, the data URIs won't work in IE due to security restrictions (http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri).
- Override `console.log`, `alert` or anything else users need in order to get feedback from their scripts in order to convert them into Web worker messages.
- Kill each Web worker after a pre-set amount of time.