# How to show the Date integer value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

After logging into MongoDB server with shell, I try the following commands

```
rs1:PRIMARY> x = Date()
Thu Dec 12 2013 11:25:58 GMT+0800 (CST)
rs1:PRIMARY> x -1
NaN
rs1:PRIMARY> print(x)
Thu Dec 12 2013 11:25:58 GMT+0800 (CST)
rs1:PRIMARY> x - 1000
NaN
```

In MongoDB doc, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/
the Date type is a 64bit integer which represents the mill-seconds since epoch. I want to show its value, but always get one string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date vs new Date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584719/date-vs-new-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a Javascript Date object.  getTime() returns the millisecond value as an integer

```
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> var now = new Date();
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> now.getTime()
1386820859427
dmReplSet:PRIMARY>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `new` operator.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
> var x = new Date()
> x - 1
1386820087199
> print(x)
Thu Dec 12 2013 01:48:07 GMT-0200 (BRST)
> x - 1000
1386820086200
```

Comment: why new Date() works but Date() doesn't? What's difference between them?