# Why is Date(N).toString() different from d= new Date(N); d.toString()

Tags: javascript

See http://worik.org/DateBug.html for an example.

```
    document.write( Date(1234).toLocaleString()+"<p/>");
```

outputs 
        Tue Aug 12 2014 09:43:22 GMT+1200 (NZST)

(as I write) but

```
    var D1 = new Date(1234);
    document.write(D1.toLocaleString()+"<p/>");
```

outputs

```
    1/01/1970 12:00:01 pm
```

I do not so much care about the format, though that is a puzzle, but the dates are different.

Worik

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9584767/1290374

Answer (score 3):

If you don't involve the `new` operator, the Date constructor returns a string representing the current time and it ignores any argument you pass.

This is the sort of question for which simple [API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is appropriate.