# Why can't Date be instantiate as not being a constructor? And other confusion

Tags: javascript, function, date, datetime, object

I am having a lot of confusion about the **Date** keyword in javascript. The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), in it's second line, states that `Date` is an object:

> `Date` objects are based on a...

But `typeof Date` returns `"function"`. Second thing is `Date()` -- with closed brackets -- should be a function because anything of type `foo()` is a function as per *Douglas Crockford's* book's chapter *Grammar*. Surprisingly enough, `typeof Date()` returns `"string"`. Now if `Date()` is not a function then what is `new Date()`? A string constructor? Precisely my questions are:

- What is `Date`? And how is it defined in javascript itself?
- What is `Date()`? How is it different from `Date`? How is it defined in javascript itself? Why is it not a function?
- What is `new Date()`? If `Date()` is a string then how can it act as constructor?
- If we can instantiate `new Date()`, e.g. like `new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")` then why can't we instantiate the original function `Date()` similarly as `Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")`?

Comment: “`Date` objects” refer to instance objects of the `Date` constructor function. `Date` is a function, `Date()` is the _result_ of the function call, which is a string. `Date` and `Date()` are different things.

Comment: Did you search Stack Overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584719/date-vs-new-date-in-javascript The fact that typeof Date returns "function" should be quite obvious: Date __is__ a function you can call, both as a function(and it will give you back a string) and as a constructor, prefixed with new. In this second case, as you noted, it will act as expected, building a new Date object.

Comment: `typeof Date()` is `string`..Of course.. It is a `typeof` value returned by `Date()`.. `Date` will hold function definition..That is the reason it is of type `function`.. `function foo()` is a function definition.. and `foo()` is invoking that function..which can return data of any primitive type.. _The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function_

Comment: Ty this: `function test() {
  return '';
}
console.log(typeof test());
var t = new test();
console.log(typeof t);`

Comment: @RayonDabre If I got you right then it means `typeof` returns the `return` value's _type_ of the function.

Comment: @user31782, There is nothing fancy about it.. This is how all the programming languages work.. _"`typeof` returns the return value's type of the function"_ function name with `parenthesis"()"` will invoke the function and will return the value mentioned in `return` keyword.. or `undefined` if `return` is missing!

Comment: The fancy thing to me here is that in javascript the return type can be _function_ -- which means `Date` returns some function.

Comment: The return type in javascript can be anything, even a function!

Comment: @Konst, Any `primitive` type to be specific...

Comment: @user31782, From docs, `typeof operand` => operand is an expression representing the object or primitive whose type "is to be returned"

Comment: I got everything now. This is how the `Date` might be defined:     `function Date2(today) {

  this.today = today;

  function curr_date() {
   return (today || "23rd april");
  }
  return alert( curr_date() );
 }
  Date2();
  var x = new Date2("24th april");
  `

Comment: In the actual version they might not use `alert()` but simply return `curr_date()`

Comment: @RayonDabre _function_ is not a primitive type in javascript. But still we can return it.

Comment: @user31782 Yes.. It is not a primitive type.. Right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ryon Dabre for clearing some doubts. First source of confusion was `typeof foo` and `type of foo()` should be the same thing but they ain't. Suppose I have a function

```
function foo() {
        var len = 10;
        alert("hello");
        return 5;
     }
```

Now `typeof foo` will return `"function"` and `typeof foo()` will return `"number"`. The statement `foo` is actually converted to foo's definition, e.g.

```
function bar(){
  return 6;
}
bar = foo;
```

`bar` becomes `foo`. Now `bar` has the return vale 5 not 6 -- just like if `var x = 1; var y = 2; x = y;` makes `x` 2. `foo` is not executed in the expression. Typing `foo` in the console returns `"function foo()"`. That is **`foo` is a variable of type function**. So type of `foo` is function.

On the other hand whenever javascript sees `foo()`, it simply executes it. So in `bar = foo()` first `foo()` will be executed. Now what will be the value assigned to `bar` -- the value returned by `foo()`. Moreover type casting will also happen here. `bar` will no longer be a function. `typeof bar` will return `"number"`. Actually `typeof foo()` and `typeof bar` both is `"number"`, with the only difference being that the statement `typeof foo()` will first execute `foo()`. In javascript `typeof foo()` is translated to two statements:
1. execute `foo`.
2. `typeof value_returned_by_foo`

---

After conceptual clarification now lets discuss about `Date()`. Date is defined something like the following:

```
function Date2(today1) {
        var today;
        this.today = today1;            
        return (today || "23rd april");
    }
```

`typeof Date2` is obviously `"function"`. Since `Date2` returns a string so `typeof Date2()` is `"string"`. `Date2()` simply returns the string "23rd April". `Date2("Monday")` also returns 23rd April because `today` remains undefined. However when `Date2` is used as constructor, `today` takes the value passed. E.g. `var crux = new Date2("Saturday");` then `crux.today` returns Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

The typeof Date returns "function" because that is the type of the Date constructor. Using `Date()` without new keyword, will return date/time in string format. But if you create `var foo = new Date()`, `typeof foo` will be object.

Comment: So does it mean that `Date()` in a statement like function call, `Date();`is a _string_, but  `Date()` in the statement `var foo = new Date()` is actually the `Date` constructor? I accept this but my question still remains. As Douglas's book `foo()` is the syntax of a function not of a string. If `Date` is a constructor then it is a function -- but where are it's closed brackets? How can the same thing `Date()` have different meanings -- Seems kinda a overloading with no parameters, strange.

Comment: @user31782, You read him wrong... `foo()` is a function invocation... `function foo(){}` is a `function-definition`.. Do not blame _Douglas_