# Why does 'Date()' return a string?

Tags: javascript

While making something, I accidentally wrote

```js
const today = Date()
```

Instead of

```js
const today = new Date()
```

And was surprised to find that this is valid syntax, and `today`'s type is a string. Moreover, `Date() === new Date().toString()` returns true.

I could not find anything in the MDN docs about this, why does this happens?

Comment: Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584719/date-vs-new-date-in-javascript

Comment: when you call `Date()` internally `(new Date()).toString()` is invoked. try running `(new Date()).toString() === Date()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN [describes this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) behavior right below the top "Syntax" section:

> Note: The only correct way to instantiate a new Date object is by using the new operator. If you simply call the Date object directly, such as now = Date(), the returned value is a string rather than a Date object.

It's described in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms):

3. If NewTarget is undefined, then

   a. Let now be the Number that is the time value (UTC) identifying the current time.

   b. Return ToDateString(now).