# How to convert Date in mongo in particular format in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have list of object in mongo mongo version I am using 4.4 ,

I have list of object something like this

```
{
    "_id" : "123456",
    "datevalue" : NumberLong(1564079400000),
}
```

now my requirement is to format the datevalue in mm/dd/yyyy format ,
This is what I am doing

```
db.repo.find({"value" : true}).forEach(data=>{
    let date = Date(data.datevalue)
    print(date)
     })
```

And I am recieving response as

```
Fri Feb 18 2022 17:21:49 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

But I require format like

```
 02/18/2022
```

Comment: It is the client which defines the output format. Check settings in your robo3T

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it doens't seem any Issue with robo3T , I have updated the question please check

Comment: Use `let date = new Date(data.datevalue)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584719/date-vs-new-date-in-javascript You should better store `Date` objects rather than number of milliseconds.

Comment: try `new Date(1564079400000).toLocaleString().split(',')[0]`

Comment: @cmgchess, this depends on your current locale and will most likely not work

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can use projection to get the output as string with your desired format.

The query do a trick, add `new Date(0)` to your milliseconds to get as `Date` object. Then you can parse to string using `$dateToString` and the format `%m/%d/%Y`.

Check the docs about [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) for more information.

```
db.repo.find({"value" : true},
{
  "datevalue": {
    "$dateToString": {
      "date": {
        "$add": [
          new Date(0),
          "$datevalue"
        ]
      },
      "format": "%m/%d/%Y"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PAUPYeqLE_J)

Comment: It is giving as unsupported projection

Comment: Maybe is Mongo version... try using `aggregate` with `$project` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tFC-XEWxfln)