# sort by high price & a-z

Tags: javascript, xml, list, sorting, dataset

can someone point me in the direction of some javascript that will help me sort lists by variables like High / low price or A to Z? something exactly like this?

i'm sure we've all seen these on amazon, ebay and other store sites.

currently using .xml datasets

Comment: what exactly do you want to sort?

Comment: exaclty that shop items title and prices from high low & from A to Z

Comment: what have you tried? there are lots of posts on SO about sorting. Need to be more specific about what you have to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

It has multiple links to other posts that tell how to accomplish this as well.

Good luck!