# Why can't JavaScript sort [5, 10, 1]?

Tags: javascript, sorting

This seems like a simple sort, yet JavaScript is giving an incorrect result.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a language quirk?

> [5, 10, 1].sort();
>
> [ 1, 10, 5 ]

Comment: Seems perfectly well ordered for a *lexical order*.

Comment: I hate to quote Atwood, but...[the first rule of programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html) is relevant here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Javascript sorts alphabetically. This means that "10" is lower than "5", because "1" is lower than "5".

To sort numerical values you need to pass in numerical comparator like this:

```
function sorter(a, b) {
  if (a < b) return -1;  // any negative number works
  if (a > b) return 1;   // any positive number works
  return 0; // equal values MUST yield zero
}

[1,10, 5].sort(sorter);
```

Or you can cheat by passing simpler function:

```
function sorter(a, b){
  return a - b;
}

[1, 10, 5].sort(sorter);
```

Logic behind this shorter function is that comparator must return `x>0 if a > b`, `x<0 if a < b` and `zero if a is equal to b`. So in case you have

```
a=1 b=5
a-b will yield negative(-4) number meaning b is larger than a

a=5 b=1
a-b will yield positive number(4) meaning a is larger than b

a=3 b=3
a-b will yield 0 meaning they are equal
```

Comment: This is WAY too much code!

Comment: @KellyJAndrews where ? Second approach is widely used. Of course you can inline it directly and minify if you prefer size > readability

Comment: I did my example in one line, The smallest you are using is 3.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews talking about reusability if you use yoursort 5 times, my code will beat yours by readability, reusability, DRY approach and if you're not happy with my approach, simply delete two newlines

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - Your one line is identical to the second example in this answer. Do you think 1 line is better than 3 because you didn't include any spaces?

Comment: Just seems like overkill to me to perform such a small task. If all you were doing was `a-b`, perfect, but if you want `b-a`, now do you need another function, or do you pass variable?  I don't think it saves you anything here. It "looks" better at first, but it's such a small thing to do. I'm all for a DRY approach as well, I'm just also an advocate for not doing something just to do it, and that's what a separate function here feels like.  Sorry to state my opinion - I'll be sure to keep it to myself next time.

Comment: I agree it may be an overkill for such a simple task but I view this problem as a reusable one. I of course will sort numbers in my application more than once so seems logical to extract it into a function. Now as I have a function, why not make it as beautiful as I can? :)

Comment: This code can be shortened using an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `numberArray.sort((a, b) => (a - b));` **Note: check if your JS engine supports Arrow Functions.**

Comment: I don't think it's "cheating" to subtract the two values, that's exactly how to compare two numeric values. The -1, +1, or 0 is the 'cheating' where you're returning a fictitious value with a 'good enough' estimate of the difference between the two values. (Additionally, under the covers `if (a < b) return -1` is going to do something like say *"subtract the values, and if the difference is negative, then evaluate to true, and if the result is true, then return negative 1"* when you could just say "return the difference, the end").

Comment: Subtracting two values and checking flag state is how comparing is done at assembly level at least on x86

Comment: this was perfect for what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass a function to the sort method.

```
var points = [5, 10, 1];
points.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/puhQ2/1/) is a working fiddle.

Comment: Also - [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) is the W3C schools details about this.

Comment: W3C schools is a bad reference

Comment: It gets a bad rap, but I think for the simple basics, it's accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Default sort order is alphabetic and ascending. If you want to sort the number you could do something like this:

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

var numArray = [140000, 104, 99];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortit(a, b){ return (a-b); }
[1, 5, 10].sort(sortit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
[5, 10, 1].sort(function(a, b){ return a - b })   # print [1, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
[5, 10, 1].sort(function(a,b){return a-b})
```