# How to sort a json with two items

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON, as seen below, and I want to sort this JSON data with rowNo and columnNo.

How can I do this?

```
jsonArrayFull: {
    Dashboard: [{
        "id": "three-col-layout-div1",
        "rowNo": "1",
        "columnNo": "0",
        "colspan": "1",
        "rowspan": "1",
        "title": "Harvester Productivity Analysis",
        "dashlet": "MIS/MISViewer/HarvesterProductivityAnalysis",
        "bgColor": "#854db0",
        "width": "31.1216429699842%",
        "height": "29.985007496251875%"
    }, {
        "id": "three-col-layout-div2",
        "rowNo": "1",
        "columnNo": "1",
        "colspan": "1",
        "rowspan": "1",
        "title": "Expense Analysis",
        "dashlet": "MIS/MISViewer/ExpenditureAnalysis",
        "bgColor": "#83a143",
        "width": "31.1216429699842%",
        "height": "29.985007496251875%"
    }, {
        "id": "three-col-layout-div3",
        "rowNo": "1",
        "columnNo": "2",
        "colspan": "1",
        "rowspan": "1",
        "title": "Labour Utilization",
        "dashlet": "MIS/MISViewer/LabourUtilization",
        "bgColor": "#a32a2a",
        "width": "31.1216429699842%",
        "height": "29.985007496251875%"
    }]
}
```

I did this script but its not working

```
for(var i=0;i<newDiv.length;i++) {
    newDiv[i].dashlets.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
        return obj1.rowNo - obj2.rowNo;
    });
}
```

Comment: You are trying to do sorting by two keys?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON defines the `Dashboard` property, but the code you've provided works with `dashlets`.

Try out this one:

```
for(var i = 0; i < newDiv.length; i++)
{
    newDiv[i].Dashboard.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
        return obj1.rowNo - obj2.rowNo;
    });
}
```

**Update**:
If you want to sort the array by two keys, please, refer this one answer:

[How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

You should add some logic into your function, it can't be done in a one stroke.

Comment: Actually... sorting with one item is working.. but i can't do it with two items.. #rowNo and #columnNo

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array of object using two keys, you could do

`Dashboard.sort(function(o1,o2){
       if( o1.rowNo == o2.rowNo ) {
                  return o1.columnNo - o2.columnNo
       }
       return o1.rowNo - o2.rowNo
});`

This one sorts first by rowNo, and then by columnNo.