# Sorting JavaScript Array Of Objects by two different values

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an object like this in JavaScript:

```
myArray[0] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"11"
myArray[1] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"15"
myArray[2] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"04"
myArray[3] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"01"
myArray[4] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"12"
myArray[5] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"02"
myArray[6] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"14"
myArray[7] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"03"
```

And I'm trying to make it to be like this:

```
myArray[0] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"01"
myArray[1] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"02"
myArray[2] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"03"
myArray[3] -> 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"04"
myArray[4] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"11"
myArray[5] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"12"
myArray[6] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"14"
myArray[7] -> 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"15"
```

As you see, I'm trying to sort it by `myArray[i][0]` at first, and then sort by `myArray[i][3]` based on the `myArray[i][0]` as index. 
I managed to sort by `myArray[i][0]` using

```
myObject.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b); 
});
```

How do I accomplish this with no libraries?

Comment: Try looking at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields

Comment: Just to check, are you sure you're using an object (`{}`) or are you rather using an array (`[]`)? When you have numeric keys, you'd generally use an array in javascript.

Comment: return parseInt(a[0] +a[1] +a[2] +a[3], 10 ) - parseInt(b[0] +b[1] +b[2] +b[3], 10 );

Comment: So you check if the `a[0] === b[0]` and if it is, then you compare `a[3]` to `b[3]` in your sort function

Comment: @user162097 to be honest I'm not an expert in Javascript, so I'm making an array of arrays, but when I get "typeof" is says "object". So I is that correct?

Comment: @MattBurland so I'd have to make a auxiliar array?

Comment: @malix I'm going to try, thank you

Comment: @Pablo: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. You have an array nested inside an array. When you sort the outer array what will get passed to the `sort` function will be the two inner arrays (they'll be `a` and `b`). So you compare the first item and then you compare the last item (if necessary)

Comment: @Pablo Yes, that's a quirk of javscript: it's traditonally returned "object" for `typeof []`, when we'd call it an array. However, newer versions of JS have introduced a function that allows you to distinguish between objects and arrays: `Array.isArray([]) === true && Array.isArray({}) === false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to sort in one run with chained comparison functions.

> How [Array#sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works:
>
> If `compareFunction` is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If `a` and `b` are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort `b` to a lower index than `a`.
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

In this case the compare function has two groups, one for sorting index `[0]` and one sorting index `[3]`. If the value at index `[0]` is equal, the the sorting for index `[3]` is taken. Both groups are chained with a logical or `||`.

```js
var array = [["62", 8, 0, "11"], ["62", 8, 0, "15"], ["48", 8, 0, "04"], ["48", 8, 0, "01"], ["62", 8, 0, "12"], ["48", 8, 0, "02"], ["62", 8, 0, "14"], ["48", 8, 0, "03"]];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) || a[3].localeCompare(b[3]);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: the use of localeCompare is a bit confusing and might give unwanted results if positions 0 and 3 are actually numeric data, in spite of being strings

Comment: if both are numbers, you can use `return a[0] - b[0] || a[3] - b[3];`

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz . It seems that this solved my problem. Could you do the kindness of explaining exactly what this code does?

Answer (score 2):

To me your variable looks like an `Array` (object indexed with integer keys) so, if it's the case, what about:

```
var ar = [
  ["62", 8, 0, "11"],
  ["62", 8, 0, "15"],
  ["48", 8, 0, "04"],
  ["48", 8, 0, "01"],
  ["62", 8, 0, "12"],
  ["48", 8, 0, "02"],
  ["62", 8, 0, "14"],
  ["48", 8, 0, "03"]
]

var result =  ar.map(function(a) {
  return {key: a.join(''), val: a}
}).sort(function(a, b){ 
  return parseInt(a.key, 10) - parseInt(b.key, 10);
}).map(function(a) {
  return a.val
})
console.log(result)
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7vrc888/)

**Edit**

The `Object` version:

```
var data = [{ 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"11"},{ 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"15"},
            { 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"04"},{ 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"01"},
            { 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"12"},{ 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"02"},
            { 0:"62", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"14"},{ 0:"48", 1:8, 2:0, 3:"03"}]

var result =  data.map(function(a) {
  return {key: [0,1,2,3].map(function(k) {return a[k]}).join(''), val: a}
}).sort(function(a, b){ 
  return parseInt(a.key, 10) - parseInt(b.key, 10);
}).map(function(a) {
  return a.val
})
console.log(result)
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7vrc888/2/)

**Edit 2**

After @malixsys's comment, here's a more efficient way:

```
var result =  data.sort(function(a, b){ 
  return parseInt(a[0]+ a[1] + a[2] + a[3], 10) - parseInt(b[0]+ b[1] + b[2] + b[3], 10);
})
```

And [corresponding updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7vrc888/3/)

Comment: Mapping, sorting and then mapping again seems horribly inefficient and unnecessary. You can sort it in a single step.

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation. I tried the last solution, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Hey! That was my comment :) but who cares...
Should have written an answer :P well done.