# Sort array of objects by multiple value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is my array of object

```
[{"name":"Tania","country":"BR"},{"name":"Carl","country":"BR"},{"name":"Farl","country":"BR"},{"name":"Rany","country":"BR"},{"name":"Ron","country":"JP"},{"name":"Antony","country":"JP"}]
```

I want to sort this array by name and same country.
This is the result

```
[{"name":"Carl","country":"BR"},{"name":"Farl","country":"BR"},{"name":"Rany","country":"BR"},{"name":"Tania","country":"BR"},{"name":"Antony","country":"JP"},{"name":"Ron","country":"JP"}]
```

To make the sort only for the name I make this, but in this case is not divided by country, how can I do this?

```
array.sort((f , n)=> {
        var nameF = f.name.toUpperCase();
        var nameN = n.name.toUpperCase();

        if(nameF < nameN) return -1;
        else if(nameF > nameN) return 1;
        else return 0
      });
```

Comment: May a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields ?

Comment: Trick for this one : If all your country codes have exactly 2 characters, you could concatenate them with the name for sorting purposes. For example : `var nameF =  f.country.toUpperCase() + f.name.toUpperCase();`.

Comment: @Protectator I suppose yes, thks work for me