# Javascript sort array using two keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi am working on a chat application, I want to sort new messages plus keeping the history order according to time.

For example, I have the chat messages in an array like this

```
[{"user":"a", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":1, "unix_time":"1474476800000"}
{"user":"b", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":1, "unix_time":"1478776800000"}
{"user":"c", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":5, "unix_time":"1479276800000"}
{"user":"d", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":1, "unix_time":"1478416800000"}
{"user":"e", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":3, "unix_time":"1478476800000"}]
```

How can I also sort them using the "msg_count" key where all greater values should come on the top but the remaining objects should be sorted with the "unix_time" key.

Comment: you can use data.sort()

Comment: May be you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields

Comment: @Cerbrus did you even read my question? i have a number and a string property to sort! All these links don't have none of that!

Comment: @Tuna: The concept is the same, but here's [another example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method with custom compare function.

```js
var data=[{"user":"a", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":1, "unix_time":"1474476800000"},
{"user":"b", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":1, "unix_time":"1478776800000"},
{"user":"c", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":5, "unix_time":"1479276800000"},
{"user":"d", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":1, "unix_time":"1478416800000"},
{"user":"e", "msg":"Hi ", "msg_count":3, "unix_time":"1478476800000"}];


data.sort(function(a, b) {
  // return the difference of `msg_count` property to sort based on them
  // if they are equal then sort based on unix_time prop
  return b.msg_count - a.msg_count || 
    b.unix_time - a.unix_time;
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Nice one, could you please add sorting for the unix_time key as well

Comment: @Tuna: He already has sorting on `unix_time` implemented there.

Comment: @Tuna : in which order

Comment: @Pranav i mean the "unix_time" property of each object in the array

Comment: The Unix_time property is not affected by your function