# Javascript - Sort Array of objects by 2 Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array of objects by 2 different properties.

These are my objects

```
array = [{ resVal: "25FA15", resFlow: 49, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 1.5 },
 { resVal: "25FA2", resFlow: 52, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "45FA2", resFlow: 53, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "35FA2", resFlow: 59, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 }]
```

I want to sort the array by the higher "resFlow" value, but with the lowest "resHP" value.

I want to put my array like this:

```
array = [{ resVal: "25FA15", resFlow: 49, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 1.5 },
{ resVal: "35FA2", resFlow: 59, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "45FA2", resFlow: 53, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
 { resVal: "25FA2", resFlow: 52, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 2 }]
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort first by `resHP` low-to-high, and then, for those with equal values, to sort by `resFlow` high-to-low?

Comment: Please [search](/help/searching) before posting. If you scroll past the accepted answer on the linked question, you'll find answers showing you how to do multiple properties as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the dupe target is horrible.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did, but also I didn't find my answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz: The answers there answer this question, which is the criterion. I'm sure you could find four others. We don't need **yet another** answer to this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use a chained approach for a specified order of keys and their sort order.

The array is sorted by the properties

- `resHP`, ascending and
- `resFlow`, descending.

It works with calculating the delta and this reflects the relation of the two objects. If the value is zero, then the two values are equal and the next delta is calculated and returned.

```js
var array = [{ resVal: "25FA15", resFlow: 49, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 1.5 }, { resVal: "25FA2", resFlow: 52, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 2 }, { resVal: "45FA2", resFlow: 53, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 }, { resVal: "35FA2", resFlow: 59, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.resHP - b.resHP || b.resFlow - a.resFlow;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

The requirement is to sort ascending by `resHP` property and then for any ties, sort descending by `resFlow` property.

Now, Javascript's [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function allows us to sort an array. It accepts one parameter, which is a *"compareFunction"*. The compareFunction accepts two parameters, which are elements of the array to be compared, and it must return their relative position in the expected resultant array.

> ```
> function compareFunction (itemA, itemB) {...}
> ```

> `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a numeric value **greater than zero** if `b` comes before `a` in the result.
>
> `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a numeric value **less than zero** if `b` comes after `a` in the result.
>
> `compareFunction(a, b)` returns **zero** if `a` and `b` are considered equivalent in terms of their relative order while sorting the array. For example, while sorting `[5, 3, 5]` both 5's are considered equivalent, hence the array should return 0 when `compareFunction(5,5)` is called.

For sorting strings, providing a `compareFunction` is not necessary. As per the specification, when compareFunction is not provided, each value in the array is converted to string, and then sorted. Here's an example:

```js
console.log('["z", "ct", "a", "aa", "ab", "bc"].sort(): ', ["z", "ct", "a", "aa", "ab", "bc"].sort());
```

### Common Mistakes:

**Comparing numbers without compareFunction**

Although compareFunction is optional by specification, if it is not provided while sorting numbers or other objects, it may result into incorrect results. Consider the example below:

```js
console.log("[1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 20].sort(): ", [1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 20].sort());
```

Here 20 appears before 3 because each number is converted to string before comparison, and since "20" comes before "3" in dictionary (if there was such a dictionary) it appears above "3" in the result.

**Returning boolean value from compareFunction instead of numeric value**

<sub>This is my mistake in the original answer.</sub>

When you return a boolean value instead of a numeric one out of the compareFunction, the boolean value is cast into a number. Meaning `true` will become 1 and `false` will become 0, but you are not returning -1.

```js
var array = [
  {
    compareThis: 1,
    originalIndex: 1
  },
  {
    compareThis: 2,
    originalIndex: 2
  },
  {
    compareThis: -1,
    originalIndex: 3
  },
  {
    compareThis: -2,
    originalIndex: 4
  }
];

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a.compareThis > b.compareThis));
```

Here the result is the unsorted, same array because when 2 and -1 are compared, the comparison 2 > -1 returns false, which is converted to 0. But when compareFunction returns 0 it indicates that the order of the two elements shall remain **unchanged**. Hence the array doesn't get sorted.

The correct way to sort this array would be:

```js
var array = [
  {
    compareThis: 1,
    originalIndex: 1
  },
  {
    compareThis: 2,
    originalIndex: 2
  },
  {
    compareThis: -1,
    originalIndex: 3
  },
  {
    compareThis: -2,
    originalIndex: 4
  }
];

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a.compareThis - b.compareThis));
```

---

So with that, the correct way to solve the problem presented in the question would be:

```js
var array = [{ resVal: "25FA15", resFlow: 49, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 1.5 },
 { resVal: "25FA2", resFlow: 52, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "45FA2", resFlow: 53, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "35FA2", resFlow: 59, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 }];


// The requirement is to sort ascending by resHP property and then for any ties, sort descending by resFlow property.
/* array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.resHP > b.resHP) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.resHP === b.resHP) {
    if (a.resFlow > b.resFlow) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.resFlow === b.resFlow) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}); */

// Simplified to the following as we are working with numbers.
array.sort(function sortByResHP(a, b) {
  return (a.resHP - b.resHP) !== 0 ? (a.resHP - b.resHP) : (b.resFlow - a.resFlow);
});

console.log("Result: ", array);
```

*Of course this can be further shortened as shown in the other answer. I am leaving the longer version of the compareFunction to make it easier to read.*

---

### Original (incorrect) answer

<s>You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for this:</s>

```
array = [{ resVal: "25FA15", resFlow: 49, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 1.5 },
 { resVal: "25FA2", resFlow: 52, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "45FA2", resFlow: 53, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "35FA2", resFlow: 59, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 }]


array.sort(function(d1,d2) {
  if(d1.resHP == d2.resHP) {
    return d1.resFlow < d2.resFlow;
  } else {
    return d1.resHP > d2.resHP;
  }
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: it's a bad example, because it does not respect the expected return value of the callback for sort. `sort` requires to get a value of smaller thena zero, zero or greater than zero. this answer returns only zero and one. that makes it not kind of symetrically, if you reverse `d1` and `d2`, for example.

Comment: @NinaScholz I never noticed that. Thanks for the explanation! :)

Comment: While I think @NinaScholz answer is cleaner, I want to commend nisarg for going through and fixing their answer, as well as providing a detailed explanation of what is going on. Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

this is a simple way to sort array of objects by multiple values

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a.firstVal.localeCompare(b.firstVal) || a.secondVal.localeCompare(b.secondVal))
```

so in your case it's gonna be

```
array.sort((a,b) => a.resHP.localeCompare(b.resHP) || b.resFlow.localeCompare(a.resFlow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a more generic solution:

```js
function sortArrayByTwoProperties(array, prop1, asc1 = true, prop2, asc2 = true) {
    return array.sort((a, b) => (
        (asc1 ? a[prop1] - b[prop1] : b[prop1] - a[prop1])
        || (asc2 ? a[prop2] - b[prop2] : b[prop2] - a[prop2])
    ));
}

array = [{ resVal: "25FA15", resFlow: 49, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 1.5 },
 { resVal: "25FA2", resFlow: 52, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "45FA2", resFlow: 53, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "35FA2", resFlow: 59, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 }]

// I want to sort the array by the higher "resFlow" value, but with the lowest "resHP" value.

// resHP ascending, resFlow descending
result = sortArrayByTwoProperties(array, "resHP", true, "resFlow", false);

console.log(result);

array_expected = [{ resVal: "25FA15", resFlow: 49, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 1.5 },
{ resVal: "35FA2", resFlow: 59, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
{ resVal: "45FA2", resFlow: 53, resName: "Rendimiento Hi-Cap Completo", resPhoto: "HighCapseries.png", resHP: 2 },
 { resVal: "25FA2", resFlow: 52, resName: "Rendimiento Tri-Seal Completo", resPhoto: "Tri-Sealseries.png", resHP: 2 }]
```