# Sort array by committee and then by user role

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that contains data similar to this:

```
var committees = [
  {
    committee: "Apple Com",
    userRole: "Member",
    membersNum: 11
  },
    {
    committee: "Orange Com",
    userRole: "Member",
    membersNum: 9
  },    {
    committee: "Banana Com",
    userRole: "",
    membersNum: 13
  },    {
    committee: "Strawberry Com",
    userRole: "Vice President",
    membersNum: 15
  },    {
    committee: "Lemon Com",
    userRole: "",
    membersNum: 13
  },
  {
    committee: "Mango Com",
    userRole: "Chair",
    membersNum: 11
  },
]
```

I want them sorted first, by the **User Role** and then by the **Committee**. The **Committee** field will always have a value, while the **User Role** field sometimes will be ***null***.

Currently, what I am doing to achieve this is break the array into two arrays. The first array will return only items which **User Role** is not ***null***. The second array returns items which **User Role** is ***null***. Next, I sort each array by **Committee** ascendingly and then I concatenate them. Thus the logic goes like this:

```
  //get committees user is member of and committees user is not member of
  var memberOf = [];
  var nonMemberOf = [];
  for(var i=0; i<committees.length; i++){
    if(committees[i].userRole){
      memberOf.push(committees[i]);
    } else {
      nonMemberOf.push(committees[i]);
    }
  }  
  memberOf.sort(function(a,b){return (a.committee > b.committee) ? 1 : -1; });
  nonMemberOf.sort(function(a,b){return (a.committee > b.committee) ? 1 : -1; });

  var allComs = memberOf.concat(nonMemberOf);
```

I've spent more than 3 hours reading  and trying to implement what I read on some posts here:

- [Javascript sort function. Sort by First then by Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175268/javascript-sort-function-sort-by-first-then-by-second)
- [Sorting an Array of Objects by two Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153846/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-two-properties)
- [Javascript - Sort Array of objects by 2 Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741397/javascript-sort-array-of-objects-by-2-properties)

I believe that there is a better way doing what I'm doing but just can't figure it out. If someone can shed some light here, I will appreciate that very much.

P.S. I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, I want to understand how to do it. For those who can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: also please share the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sort`ing by the Boolean difference between each compared item's `userRole`, or if that comes out to `0` (that is, if both have a role or both don't have a role), then sort by their `committee`s:

```js
var committees=[{committee:"Apple Com",userRole:"Member",membersNum:11},{committee:"Orange Com",userRole:"Member",membersNum:9},{committee:"Banana Com",userRole:"",membersNum:13},{committee:"Strawberry Com",userRole:"Vice President",membersNum:15},{committee:"Lemon Com",userRole:"",membersNum:13},{committee:"Mango Com",userRole:"Chair",membersNum:11},]

committees.sort((a, b) => (
  Boolean(b.userRole) - Boolean(a.userRole)
  || a.committee.localeCompare(b.committee)
));
console.log(committees);
```

Comment: This certainly does the trick. I believe then, that I will need to understand more in detail how the sort() works and also the localeCompare()