# Sort Array with Two Factors | Score and Time Taken

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array like following

```
[{
  "score": 12,
  "time": 97192
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 144391
},
{
  "score": 15,
  "time": 900039
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 143962
}]
```

I want to have the result like the following

```
[
{
  "score": 15,
  "time": 900039
},
{
  "score": 12,
  "time": 97192
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 143962
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 144391 
}]
```

The score should be sorted in descending order while the time for the same score should be sorted in ascending order.

```js
  newScoreArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.score === b.score) {
      var x = a.timeTaken,
        y = b.timeTaken;
        if(x>y){
          return -1;
        }else{
          return 1;
        }
    }
    return b.score - a.score;
  });
```

But this is just sorting according to the score only. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here. Also if you have a better idea then please help me with it.

Comment: `newScoreArray.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score || a.time - b.time)` or `newScoreArray.sort(({score: scoreA, time: timeA}, {score: scoreB, time: timeB}) => scoreA - scoreB || timeA - timeB)` would be the idiomatic way. `a - b` for numbers, `a.localeCompare(b)` for strings, chained with `||`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by two values prioritizing on one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Sort Array of objects by 2 Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741397/javascript-sort-array-of-objects-by-2-properties)

Comment: @MarkMeyer Nope its slightly different from that, I already tried that solution before posting this question.

Comment: @Xufox Nope its slightly different from that, I already tried that solution too before posting this question.

Comment: If you want to change the order, just swap the operands: instead of `a - b` use `b - a`.

Comment: @Xufox I have tried it. Does not work.

Comment: @MarsMoon: This answer is from that question and delivers your desired results : `data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.score - a.score || a.time - b.time;
});`

Answer (score 1):

This is rather very easy

```js
let a = [{
  "score": 12,
  "time": 97192
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 144391
},
{
  "score": 15,
  "time": 900039
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 143962
}]

// for ascending sort
a.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a.score == b.score) return a.time - b.time;
  return a.score - b.score;
})

// for your case 
a.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a.score == b.score) return a.time - b.time;
  return b.score - a.score;
})


console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately its not working on my case. I have updated the question, please review it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to be really terse:

```
let a = [{
  "score": 12,
  "time": 97192
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 144391
},
{
  "score": 15,
  "time": 900039
},
{
  "score": 3,
  "time": 143962
}]

a.sort((a,b) => b.score - a.score || a.time - b.time)

console.log(a)
```

If scores are equal, `b.score - a.score` evaluates to 0 (false) so the times will be used.

Comment: Your output is wrong. `score` is in `asc` order when the OP asked for `desc`.

Comment: Answer edited to sort by score descending. See https://jsbin.com/nehuwateli/1/edit?js,console for demo.