# How to sort by the result of multiple columns division with Sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Here I want to sort by the result of multiple columns division, like:

`ORDER BY col1 / col2 DESC`

Or,

`ORDER BY col2 / col3 / col4 ASC`.

Is there some way to sort like this using sequelize.js ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lastest Sequelize.js, I find out this way to solve the question:

```
 order: [
   [
     {
       raw: 'col1 / col2 DESC',
     },
   ],
 ],
```