# Sort array of objects having the offsets in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I am new to `web development`. Here, I do have an array which is like

```
[{
        endOffset: "50"
        startOffset: "25"
        type: "Education"
    },
    {
        endOffset: "67"
        startOffset: "55"
        type: "address"
    },
    {
        endOffset: "65"
        startOffset: "59"
        type: "project"
    },
    {
        endOffset: "80"
        startOffset: "70"
        type:"fullname"
    }]
```

In this array of objects , now I am sorting it on the basis of the endoffsets . Which is like ->

```
jsonDataArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.startOffset - b.startOffset;
          });
```

Then Its giving me the sorted array. But here it is sorting on the basis of only `startoffset`.

What I want is that I want to have an array like which will have sort on ascending order of both start and endoffset, so that the array will be like

```
[{
 starOffset: "25",
 type: "Education"
}, {
 endOffset: "50"
 type: "Education" },

{
 startoffset: "55"
 type: "address" },
{
 startoffset: "59"
 type: "project" },
{
 endoffset: "65"
 type: "project" },

{
 endoffset: "67"
 type: "address" 
},
{
 endoffset: "67"
 type: "address" 
},
{
 startOffset: "70"
 type: "address" 
},
{
 endoffset: "80"
 type: "address" 
},
```

]

So, How can I do this ? Can any one please help me with this ?

Comment: You can check this topic: "[How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)", it seems related to your issue.

Comment: To save you from future headaches/problems: There's no [JSON](http://json.org) involved in your code - `jsonDataArray` is an array of objects and is not in any way related to JSON.

Comment: Okay thanks. for this.

Comment: So if startOffset is the same you want to sort by endOffset?

Comment: So, In this case the one which appeared first will added first in array

Answer (score 1):

First create the desired array with `startOffset` and `endOffset` in separate object then you can assign the value for `aVal` and `bVal` to sort for by having condition in your `sort` function as mentioned below in code:

```js
var jsonDataArray = [{
        endOffset: "50",
        startOffset: "25",
        type: "Education"
    },
    {
        endOffset: "67",
        startOffset: "65",
        type: "address"
    },
    {
        endOffset: "65",
        startOffset: "59",
        type: "project"
    },
    {
        endOffset: "80",
        startOffset: "70",
        type:"fullname"
    }];

var newJSON = [];
jsonDataArray.forEach((obj)=>{
  var  tempObj = {
     endOffset: obj.endOffset,
     type: obj.type
  };
  newJSON.push(tempObj);
  tempObj = {
     startOffset: obj.startOffset,
     type: obj.type
  };
  newJSON.push(tempObj);
});
newJSON.sort(function (a, b) {
  var aVal = a.startOffset?a.startOffset:a.endOffset;
  var bVal = b.startOffset?b.startOffset:b.endOffset;
  return aVal - bVal;
});
console.log(newJSON);
```

Comment: Here the first one is my jsonData array. The next one is my expected output.

Comment: Hey, what will happen if the offsets are same ?

Comment: They will still work because there is a condition there if it found `startOffset` present in object it will use that else it will use `endOffset` and the code is certain that there will be either `startOffset` or `endOffset` @ganeshkaspate

Comment: @ganeshkaspate you can use this instead of really abstract code as this will allow you to change your code easily and it is also lot more understanding when you look at a glance

Comment: Okay Ankit. Thanks for the help. Great solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170090/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-ganesh-kaspate).

Comment: Here , If you have a 0 value as a startoffset then this is not sorting according to that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new array with start and end values and sort them by taking either the start or end value.

```js
var data = [{ endOffset: "50", startOffset: "25", type: "Education" }, { endOffset: "67", startOffset: "55", type: "address" }, { endOffset: "65", startOffset: "59", type: "project" }, { endOffset: "80", startOffset: "70", type: "fullname" }],
    extended = data.reduce(
        (r, { endOffset, startOffset, type }) =>
            r.concat({ startOffset, type }, { endOffset, type }), []);

extended.sort((a, b) => (a.startOffset || a.endOffset) - (b.startOffset || b.endOffset));

console.log(extended);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var data = [{ endOffset: "50", startOffset: "25", type: "Education" }, { endOffset: "67", startOffset: "55", type: "address" }, { endOffset: "65", startOffset: "59", type: "project" }, { endOffset: "80", startOffset: "70", type: "fullname" }],
    extended = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        return r.concat(
            { startOffset: o.startOffset, type: o.type },
            { endOffset: o.endOffset, type: o.type }
        );
    }, []);

extended.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.startOffset || a.endOffset) - (b.startOffset || b.endOffset);
});

console.log(extended);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sorts on startOffset first then by endOffset:

```js
const array = [{
  endOffset: "50",
  startOffset: "25",
  type: "Education"
},
{
  endOffset: "67",
  startOffset: "55",
  type: "address"
},
{
  endOffset: "65",
  startOffset: "59",
  type: "project"
},
{
  endOffset: "80",
  startOffset: "70",
  type:"fullname"
}]

console.log(
  array.reduce(
    (result,item)=>result.concat([
      {startOffset:item.startOffset,type:item.type},
      {endOffset:item.endOffset,type:item.type}
    ]),
    []
  ).sort(
    (a,b)=>(a.startOffset||a.endOffset)-(b.startOffset||b.endOffset)
  )
)
```

Comment: And I am using ES5

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Then you use type `functrion(){return` instead of `()=>`

Comment: This is nice .Actually, I want to have this in the seperate way, like the array which I given.

Comment: It does not natter for me start or end as long as there is an ascending order .

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Ok, I think I understand what you wanted. Updated the answer.