# Ranking object keys based on a given criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object:

```
let res = {
   'name': {
      age: 10,
      density: 33,
      length: 2
    },
    'greet': {
       age: 33,
       density: 92,
       length: 3
    },
    'gyrt': {
        age: 91,
        density: 2,
        length: 47
     },
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Which has much more key value pairs. I am asked to return the list of keys in the descending order of "ranking" which is governed by the below constraints:

- Greater age must be ranked higher
- Words with low density must be ranked higher
- Words with high length must be ranked higher

I am confused how to achieve this. I am trying to sort object but that does not help. I first tried to sort with `age`, then with `density`, and then with `length` but it clearly does not work because object is re-ordered again and again while forgetting the previous order. How could I achieve this?

This is what I was trying:

```
let sortByAge = keys.sort((a, b) => Number(res[b].age) - Number(res[a].age));

let sortByDensity = keys.sort((a, b) => Number(res[b].density) - Number(res[a].density));
```

And same with `length`. I cannot understand how to combine all the factors and order them.

Comment: Can you share an attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: Tip: you can't sort object you can sort array though, Try `const sorted = Object.entries(a).sort(...)

Comment: @LucaKiebel I pasted the snippet in the question using which I was trying to sort.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields) there is a similar problem with a generic solution.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields) there is a similar problem with a generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put some conditions into your sort function that check whether or not the age, or the density are equal, and if they are, sort by the next set of rules (age -> density -> length):

```js
let a={'name':{age:10,density:33,length:2},'greet':{age:33,density:92,length:3},'gyrt':{age:91,density:2,length:47},'foo':{age:91,density:3,length:47},'bar':{age:91,density:2,length:30},'baz':{age:10,density:2,length:47},'boo':{age:91,density:2,length:47},}

let sorted = Object.values(a);

sorted.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.age === b.age) {
    if(a.density === b.density) {
      //sort by length
      return b.length - a.length;
    }
    //sort by density
    return a.density - b.density;
  }
  //sort by age
  return b.age - a.age;
});

console.log(sorted)
```

To sort the keys (sorting values is better for showing how it works), just replace `a` and `b` by `obj[a]` and `obj[b]`

```js
let obj={'name':{age:10,density:33,length:2},'greet':{age:33,density:92,length:3},'gyrt':{age:91,density:2,length:47},'foo':{age:91,density:3,length:47},'bar':{age:91,density:2,length:30},'baz':{age:10,density:2,length:47},'boo':{age:91,density:2,length:47},}

let sorted = Object.keys(obj);

sorted.sort((a,b) => {
  if(obj[a].age === obj[b].age) {
    if(obj[a].density === obj[b].density) {
      //sort by length
      return obj[b].length - obj[a].length;
    }
    //sort by density
    return obj[a].density - obj[b].density;
  }
  //sort by age
  return obj[b].age - obj[a].age;
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Words with greater `age` must be ranked higher. Words with low `density`  must be ranked higher. Currently it prints age with 10 on the top.

Comment: Check it now please

Comment: Just realized it, I changed it a total of one million times while writing the answer ^^

Comment: Also, how could I get just the `keys`?

Comment: I added an example of how to do that as well

Comment: How could I modify this if the condition changes to `Words with high density must be ranked higher`?

Comment: invert the order of `obj[a].density - obj[b].density;`, so that `obj[a]` gets subtracted from `obj[b]`, to `obj[b].density - obj[a].density;`

Comment: I was trying with a different condition here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zrkvqd3/) , where high rank will be ranked higher, high occurance will be ranked higher and low length will be ranked higher. But I am making some mistake as I try to emulate your method. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It does not work. The occurances and length are both jumbled up.

Comment: @HenryRon Consider what you're saying. The `occurances` are only used as a criteria if the `rank` is the same, and the `length` are only used as a criteria if both the `rank` and `occurances` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sortBy()` function I introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398944/1541563), you can create a sorting method that combines each property like so:

```js
const res = {name:{age:10,density:33,length:2},greet:{age:33,density:92,length:3},gyrt:{age:91,density:2,length:47},foo:{age:91,density:3,length:47},bar:{age:91,density:2,length:30},baz:{age:10,density:2,length:47},boo:{age:91,density:2,length:47}}

const sortBy = fn => (a, b) => -(fn(a) < fn(b)) || +(fn(a) > fn(b))
const pick = key => ({ [key]: value }) => value
const age = sortBy(pick('age'))
const density = sortBy(pick('density'))
const length = sortBy(pick('length'))
const sortFn = (a, b) =>
  -age(a[1], b[1]) ||
  density(a[1], b[1]) ||
  -length(a[1], b[1])

const keys = Object.entries(res).sort(sortFn).map(([key, value]) => key)

console.log(keys)
```