# How to sort div order position by data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I want to reorder my divs according to the `data-position`, I tried this but it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery("#bout div.foot").sort(function(a, b) {
  var position = jQuery(this).attr("data-position");
  return parseInt(a.position) - parseInt(b.position);
}).each(function() {
  var elem = jQuery(this);
  elem.remove();
  jQuery(elem).appendTo("#bout");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container vendors" id="bout">
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="3">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="1">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the `this` keyword in the `sort()` handler whereas you instead need to use the `a` and `b` element references in order to compare them. You can also use `data()` instead of `attr()` to return the attributes. This will also return an integer to negate the need for `parseInt()`. Once the elements are sorted you can just `append()` them to the container without the extra `each()` loop. Try this:

```js
$("#bout div.foot").sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data("position") - $(b).data("position");
}).appendTo("#bout");

// alternative #1
// $("#bout div.foot").sort((a, b) => $(a).data("position") - $(b).data("position")).appendTo("#bout");

// alternative #2
// $("#bout div.foot").sort((a, b) => a.dataset.position - b.dataset.position).appendTo("#bout");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container vendors" id="bout">
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="3">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 foot" data-position="1">1</div>
</div>
```

Note that the logic does not deal with duplicate values in the sort algorithm, so you will need to implement a secondary method of sorting, if required.

Comment: Great, thanks for your time

Comment: a small question, do you know how to add also the order by name exemple if i have `data-position` values: 1, 1, 1, 2, for the 4 divs, so it order them by name for the the first three then 2 Please ?

Comment: That's what my final note mentions. You'll need to amend the logic to detect when the values match, then order by something else. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6913512/519413) a question which covers how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Without jQuery, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and conveniently wrapped in a reusable function:

```js
function sortChildren(containerSelector, reverse) {
  const container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
  const order = reverse ? -1 : 1;
  
  Array.from(container.children)
    .sort((a, b) => order * parseInt(a.dataset.position, 10) - order * parseInt(b.dataset.position, 10))
    .forEach(element => container.appendChild(element));
    
  // Note you could also conditionally use Array.reverse() instead of the order variable.
}

sortChildren('#container1');
sortChildren('#container2', true);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 16px 0 0;
}

.container > li {
  padding: 4px 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container" id="container1">
    <li data-position="4">4</li>
    <li data-position="3">3</li>
    <li data-position="4">4</li>
    <li data-position="1">1</li>
    <li data-position="6">6</li>
</ul>

<ul class="container" id="container2">
    <li data-position="1">1</li>
    <li data-position="2">2</li>
    <li data-position="3">3</li>
    <li data-position="4">4</li>
    <li data-position="5">5</li>
    <li data-position="6">6</li>
    <li data-position="7">7</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, there's no need to remove the elements, as when they are appended they will automatically be moved from their previous position to the new one.