# How to compare element in a nest array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I need to sort out element in a nested array.

In each nest array there is 1 string and 1 integer.

```
var arr1 = [["2000", 2], ["11", 2], ["11", 2], ["10003", 4], ["22", 4], ["123", 6], ["1234000", 10], ["44444444", 32], ["9999", 36]]
```

I need to sort out the array by ascending integer (not the string). Which I can do by doing this:

```
var res = arr1.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

However, when 2 integers have the same value, I need to sort them by their string (only for the matching integers, not for the rest of the array).

The result should be:

```
[["11", 2], ["11", 2], ["2000", 2], ["10003", 4], ["22", 4], ["123", 6], ["1234000", 10], ["44444444", 32], ["9999", 36]]
```

I can't figure how to make this happen. I tried a for loop but keep getting an error.

Anyone to help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: The [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256174/5260024) at the dupe is actually not the most upper one ... TLDR: `return a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the sort by sorting with the first index.

BTW, [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), sort the array [*in situ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ), that means the array mutates the order of the items.

```js
var array = [["2000", 2], ["11", 2], ["11", 2], ["10003", 4], ["22", 4]] ;

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1] || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina Sholz!

Comment: Turned out this solution doesn't work as it doesn't sort out ALL the nested array the same way.
this array : [["2000", 2], ["11", 2], ["11", 2], ["10003", 4], ["22", 4]]

Should be: [["11", 2], ["11", 2], ["2000", 2], ["22", 4], ["10003", 4]]

Thanks!

Comment: what does not work? how nested is the array?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: do you want to sort by string if the second item is equal? please see edit.

Comment: Yes exactly. This works, however, I am not sure to understand why. I will have to look into it. Thanks!