# How to sort array objects one property value is ascending and another property value is descending order in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is the array

```
[  
   {  
      "contest_id":1,
      "points":10
   },
   {  
      "contest_id":2,
      "points":10
   },
   {  
      "contest_id":1,
      "points":11
   },
   {  
      "contest_id":2,
      "points":9
   },
   {  
      "contest_id":1,
      "points":12
   }
]
```

In the above array contains list of objects, sort the array of objects based property values like `contest_id` with ascending order , `points` are descending order . 
Output :-

```js
Contest_id    points

1             12
1             11
1             10
2             10
2             9
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields This should help

Comment: list.sort((a,b) => a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1)

Comment: `list.sort((a,b) => a.contest_id< b.contest_id? 1 : a.contest_id> b.contest_id?-1:a.points>b.points?1:a.points<b.points?-1:0)`. I don't test, but remember, sort must return 1, -1 or 0