# Problem with filter and sort of a list Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, filtering

I have a sorted alphabetically list. Then I'm filtering it. If I find an object matching my pattern, I'm pushing it's index into an indexArray. I want to move "found" objects to the begining of the list using splice like this:

```
this.indexArray.foreach(index => {
    this.sortedList.splice(0, 1 , this.sortedList.splice(indexOfFoundObject,1)[0]);
}
```

Unfortunatelly the result I'm getting is not what I expect. I get list like :
List Of Found Objects Sorted From Z to A (instead of A to Z)
List Of The Rest sorted properly from A to Z.
I was trying to make indexArray.reverse, or this.indexArray.reverse().forEach() but then I'm not getting a filtered list at all. How can I change my code so that the list Of Found Objects would be sorted from A to Z? maybe I have some error in my splice function?

I've tried to do this with 1 sort function with 3 sorting conditions but it still isn't working as expected.

```
this.list.sort(function (a, b) {
   if(a.data.phaseName.toLowerCase().includes(filterParam.value.toLowerCase()) ||
      b.data.phaseName.toLowerCase().includes(filterParam.value.toLowerCase())) {
         if(a.data.phaseName.toLowerCase().includes(filterParam.value.toLowerCase()) &&                  b.data.phaseName.toLowerCase().includes(filterParam.value.toLowerCase())) {
              a.data.toExpand = true;
              a.data.toColor = true;
              b.data.toColor = true;
              b.data.toExpand = true;
              return b.data.phaseName.toLowerCase() < a.data.phaseName.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
                } else if (a.data.phaseName.toLowerCase().includes(filterParam.value.toLowerCase())) {
                    a.data.toExpand = true;
                    a.data.toColor = true;
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    b.data.toColor = true;
                    b.data.toExpand = true;
                    return 1;
                }
            } if (a.data.status === b.data.status) {
                a.data.toExpand = false;
                a.data.toColor = false;
                b.data.toColor = false;
                b.data.toExpand = false;
                return b.data.phaseName.toLowerCase() < a.data.phaseName.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return b.data.status < a.data.status ? 1 : -1;
    });
```

So I'm expecting to get list sorted like this:
1. all data with names containing given string in alphabetical order
2. rest of data (not containing given string) sorted by status Open/Closed
3. inside each of the status the data should be sorted in aphabetical order as well

But what I;m getting is:
1. all data sorted by status Open/Closed
2. inside each of the status the data should be sorted in aphabetical order as well
3. The data which contains given string have given colors and are expanded.
I don't understand why the first if is acting as least important

Comment: Why not sort the list by found (what you are doing in the filter) and then alphabetically in the same sort statement? See also [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6913512/1260204)

Comment: Because I neet to do it independly. First I'm sorting a non filtered list by status of object and inside the statuses alphabetically. Then as a result of filter I neet to put ALL found elements to the top regardless of it's statuses.

Comment: Still sounds like you need 1 sort with 3 sort conditions

Comment: Hmm ok I tried to do it wih 1 sort, but I still can't figure it out. I've edited the question to upload last code