# Sort array of objects by multiple properties of string type

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, conditional-operator

I am sorting my array in JavaScript based on names after then I am sorting it based in `joinDate` but somehow it is not checking for `joiningDate`.

Unfortunately, I can't use an if-else condition - I only want to use ternary operators.

My code is like this:

```
person.sort(((a, b) => (a.name > b.name)  ? 1 : (a.joinDate > b.joinDate) ? 1 : -1));
```

It is sorting the names but not sorting the `joinDate` property

My list look like this:

```
{
"data": [
     {
         "id": "fdsf",
         "name": "Julie",
         "joinDate": "01/10/2019"

      },
    ]
}
```

Comment: You aren't covering all 4 cases :) And why didn't you post it to your previous question here?

Comment: It's not clear why you think an array of length 1 is sufficient to test a sorting function(!) But your code contains a logical error, as presumably you always want to return `-1` if `a.name < b.name`, rather than fall back to comparing the `joinDate` properties. This will rapidly get very messy to do with nested ternaries - as a general rule I would say NEVER nest more than 2 ternaries, and be very wary of even nesting 2 of them.

Comment: your sort by joinDate will put "02/03/2018" AFTER  "01/10/2019"  which is a bit strange

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+sort+by+multiple+keys) of [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256174/4642212).

Comment: Consider using ISO dates for `joinDate`, i.e. `2019-10-01` (`yyyy-MM-dd`) instead of `01/10/2019`. One of the main advantages is that they sort naturally alphanumerically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test should be (assuming your date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`)

```
if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
let [a_dd, a_mm, a_yy] = a.joindate.split("/");
let [b_dd, b_mm, b_yy] = b.joindate.split("/");
if (a_yy !== b_yy) return a_yy - b_yy;
if (a_mm !== b_mm) return a_mm - b_mm;
if (a_dd !== b_dd) return a_dd - b_dd;
return 0;
```

Comment: Or in insane ternary: `a.name > b.name ? 1
: a.name < b.name ? -1
: a.joindate > b.joindate ? 1
: a.joindate < b.joindate ? -1
: 0`

Comment: regarding that ternary... please don't do that to the next person who has to decipher your code :)

Comment: @Sheraff Perfect. it's for personal use so I little messy code is okay as long as it work :-p Thanks!

Comment: @NehaSharma I wrote this as a joke... -_-

Answer (score 10):

Your comparison function does not cover all the possible cases properly.

Instead, you may use [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort by either `name` or `joinDate` (when names are same) like that:

```
person.sort((a,b) => 
   a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.joinDate.localeCompare(b.joinDate))
```

I guess, that approach would be much easier to scale to arbitrary number of sorting parameters.