# How to order an array of objects by date and by time at once

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi all I need some help sorting an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "jobID": "202012101329yXHTXvqg",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:26",
        "jobEnd": "13:31:58"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "2020121013290Yyjny8x",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:58",
        "jobEnd": "13:30:36"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:28:09",
        "jobEnd": "09:28:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120927afObyUv8",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:27:42",
        "jobEnd": "09:27:58"
    }
]
```

I'd like to sort it by jobDate and by jobEnd in a desc order:

```
[
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:28:09",
        "jobEnd": "09:28:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120927afObyUv8",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:27:42",
        "jobEnd": "09:27:58"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202012101329yXHTXvqg",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:26",
        "jobEnd": "13:31:58"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "2020121013290Yyjny8x",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:58",
        "jobEnd": "13:30:36"
    }
]
```

I have tried to use various methods but I can only sort by one value, instead I have to sort by two values at once (jobsDate and jobsEnd). How would you deal with this problem?

Comment: Which is more prior than the other? Let's say if 2 objects have the same date? or have the same time?

Comment: @KienHT 1st sort by jobsDate and 2nd each jobsDate must be sorted by jobsEnd.

Comment: You can provide custom function to `sort` method. Inside this function you need to create `Date` object from `jobDate`  `jobEnd` time and use it for desc sorting as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Comment: Is `"12-10-2020"` supposed to be MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: @VLAZ yes it is "MM-DD-YYYY"

Comment: This question asks the same as this one: [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One just needs to write a ([sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax)) function which, always in descending order, does compare at first the `jobDate`s of two items, and in case both dates are equal, continues comparing both item's `jobEnd` values.

In case of `jobDate` one has to either validly convert each value into a `Date` type before passing it to `compareDescending` or reformat it for direct comparison from `MM-DD-YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-DD` (which is the current use case).

Both string values of each `jobEnd` can be compared directly via `compareDescending` because the `hh:mm:ss` format is provided on a `24`hour base.

```js
function sanitizeDateFormat(str) {
  const [month, day, year] = str.split('-');
  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
function compareDescending(a, b) {
  return ((a > b) && -1) || ((a < b) && 1) || 0;
}

function compareJobsByDateAndEndTime(a, b) {
  return compareDescending(

    // new Date(a.jobDate),
    // new Date(b.jobDate)
    sanitizeDateFormat(a.jobDate),
    sanitizeDateFormat(b.jobDate)

  ) || compareDescending(

    a.jobEnd,
    b.jobEnd
  );
}

console.log([{
  "jobID": "2020121013290Yyjny8x",
  "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
  "jobStart": "13:29:58",
  "jobEnd": "13:30:36"
}, {
  "jobID": "202012101329yXHTXvqg",
  "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
  "jobStart": "13:29:26",
  "jobEnd": "13:31:58"
}, {
  "jobID": "202011120927afObyUv8",
  "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
  "jobStart": "09:27:42",
  "jobEnd": "09:27:58"
}, {
  "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
  "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
  "jobStart": "09:28:09",
  "jobEnd": "09:28:25"
}].sort(compareJobsByDateAndEndTime));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

> *Please, can you explain what it does ? `((a > b) && -1) || ((a < b) && 1) || 0` – Luca Donnaloia*

A comparator function, which by default does a comparison for an *ascending order*, is expected to return a value *grater than Zero* in case its first argument is found to be somehow "grater" than its second value; likewise with a return value *lower than Zero* which indicates that the first argument is minor in comparison to the second argument. A return value of *Zero* indicates the equality of both argument's order/sequence. A comparator which helps sorting in *descending order* then needs to flip the return values for *grater than* and *lower than*.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const jobDate = [
    {
        "jobID": "202012101329yXHTXvqg",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:26",
        "jobEnd": "13:31:58"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "2020121013290Yyjny8x",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:58",
        "jobEnd": "13:30:36"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:28:09",
        "jobEnd": "09:28:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120927afObyUv8",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:27:42",
        "jobEnd": "09:27:58"
    }
];

function sortDate() {
  jobDate.sort((a,b) => {
   const d = new Date(b.jobDate.split("-").reverse().join("-")) - new Date(a.jobDate.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
     if (d === 0) {
       return a.jobEnd.localeCompare(b.jobEnd);
     }
     return d;
   });
  console.log(jobDate);
}

//sortDate("jobDate");
sortDate();
```

Comment: This works too but I've edited it to fit my question (sorting desc):

`function sortDate(arr) {
arr.sort((a, b) => {
const d =
new Date(b.jobDate.split('-').reverse().join('-')) -
new Date(a.jobDate.split('-').reverse().join('-'));
if (d === 0) {
return b.jobEnd.localeCompare(a.jobEnd);
} 
return d;
});
}

sortDate(jobDate);`

Comment: ok, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        jobID: '202012101329yXHTXvqg',
        jobDate: '12-10-2020',
        jobStart: '13:29:26',
        jobEnd: '13:31:58',
    },
    {
        jobID: '2020121013290Yyjny8x',
        jobDate: '12-10-2020',
        jobStart: '13:29:58',
        jobEnd: '13:30:36',
    },
    {
        jobID: '202011120928w28NDLQVu',
        jobDate: '12-11-2020',
        jobStart: '09:28:09',
        jobEnd: '09:28:25',
    },
    {
        jobID: '202011120927afObyUv8',
        jobDate: '12-11-2020',
        jobStart: '09:27:42',
        jobEnd: '09:27:58',
    },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    const aDateAsArr = a.jobDate.split('-');
    const aTimeASArr = a.jobEnd.split(':');

    const bDateAsArr = b.jobDate.split('-');
    const bTimeASArr = b.jobEnd.split(':');

    const aDate = new Date(
        +aDateAsArr[2],
        +aDateAsArr[1],
        +aDateAsArr[0],
        +aTimeASArr[0],
        +aTimeASArr[1],
        +aTimeASArr[2],
    );
    const bDate = new Date(
        +bDateAsArr[2],
        +bDateAsArr[1],
        +bDateAsArr[0],
        +bTimeASArr[0],
        +bTimeASArr[1],
        +bTimeASArr[2],
    );

    return bDate.getTime() - aDate.getTime();
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a good solution too.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is that your date is in MM-DD-YYYY format, which means it needs to be changed in order to be easily comparable to another date. The easiest way it to tranform to YYYY-MM-DD (ISO 8601 format) - in that case, lexicograpgical sorting is the same as chronological sorting, so you can directly compare the two dates as strings. Times can already compared that way.

With some abstraction and generalisation, you can get to an easily compostable solution:

```js
/*   library code   */

const extractField = prop => x =>
  x[prop];

const pipe = (first, ...fns) => (...args) =>
  fns.reduce((result, fn) => fn(result), first(...args));

const compare = (normalise = x => x) => (a, b) =>
  (a = normalise(a)) === (b = normalise(b))
  ? 0 
  : a > b
    ? 1 
    : -1;

const sortingBy = (...criteria) => (a, b) =>
  criteria.reduce((acc, c) => acc || c(a, b), 0);

const flip = f => (a, b) => 
  f(b, a);

/*   /library code   */


/*   sorting code   */

//MM-DD-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD
const formatDate = str => 
  str.replace(/(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)/, "$3-$1-$2");

//get jobDate -> sort as formatted date
const comparableDate = pipe(extractField("jobDate"), formatDate);

const compareDatesAsc = compare(comparableDate);
const compareDatesDesc = flip(compareDatesAsc);
const compareTimesAsc = compare(extractField("jobEnd"));

const comparator = sortingBy(
  compareDatesDesc,
  compareTimesAsc
);

/*   /sorting code   */

const arr = [
    {
        "jobID": "202012101329yXHTXvqg",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:26",
        "jobEnd": "13:31:58"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "2020121013290Yyjny8x",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:58",
        "jobEnd": "13:30:36"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:28:09",
        "jobEnd": "09:28:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2019",
        "jobStart": "10:28:09",
        "jobEnd": "10:28:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2021",
        "jobStart": "09:58:09",
        "jobEnd": "09:58:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120927afObyUv8",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:27:42",
        "jobEnd": "09:27:58"
    }
]

arr.sort(comparator);
console.log(arr);
```

### More detailed explanation

This is a generalised comparison criteria:

```
const compare = (normalise = x => x) => (a, b) =>
  (a = normalise(a)) === (b = normalise(b))
  ? 0 
  : a > b
    ? 1 
    : -1;
```

You can supply your normalisation function that will transform `a` and `b` to something that can be easily compared, so it can work for any data type that obeys the `<`, and `>` operators, like numbers, strings, dates, etc.

This is a generalised sorting algorithm:

```
const sortingBy = (...criteria) => (a, b) =>
  criteria.reduce((acc, c) => acc || c(a, b), 0);
```

It takes any amount of sorting criteria and will run `a` and `b` through each until one returns something different from `0`.

These two enable us to generalise any sorting as a collection of criteria.

Some helpers are also defined as library code, as they aren't specific to the sorting operation:

- `extractField` is fairly self-explanatory and will extract a field by name from an object.
- `pipe` is a small helper method to compose functions together: `g(f(x)) = pipe(f, g)(x)`.
- `flip` reverses the arguments for a function. Useful here as it allows to create opposite sorting criteria from existing ones, since  `compare(x, y)` must be symmetrically opposite to `compare(y, x)`.

Library code aside, the actual sorting logic consists of defining what we sort by and in what order:

- `formatDate` is the only custom function to transform to an ISO8601 date.
- `comparableDate` is derived from existing functions: extracting `jobDate` and formatting it
- `compareDatesAsc` and `compareTimesAsc` are also derived as sorting criteria.
- `compareDatesDesc` is reverse sorting derived for free.
- `comparator` is finally the final logic based on the two existing ones in order.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the effort to explain your answer in detail, I have learned something new! I changed the backend code, so now it sends me the dates in ISO8601 format. I think I'll generalize the comparison part to accept "jobDate" rather than "jobEnd" or whatever arguments you want to pass to the extraField function, ascendingSort and descendingSort are a very welcome bonus :)

Comment: Although this was the most detailed answer I received, unfortunately it doesn't work as expected because the result is not right (unlike other answers with even simpler methods). Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LucaDonnaloia which input produces the wrong result? I seem to get the results you expected when doing a descending sort.

Comment: look at your output code: there is one element, the last of the output, which is not sorted, "12-11-2019" should be at the beginning of the output with the other days like 12-11-2019

Comment: @LucaDonnaloia ah, I see what you mean now. It's ascending by date but descending by time, correct?

Comment: it's desc by date and by time per day, ie:

`1. 2020-12-11 18:00
2. 2020-12-11 08:00
3. 2020-12-10 12:30
4. 2020-12-08 08:00
5. 2020-12-08 06:00
6. 2020-07-31 16:00
7. 2019-12-31 08:00`

Comment: @LucaDonnaloia Thanks. I have apparently misread the question the first time around, I thought you wanted ascending dates and times. I've updated to a descending dates and ascending times. Works out better, as I wanted to showcase how to reverse a sorting criteria with `flip`. Using it to have two sorting criteria one ascending one descending I think is an even better example.

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [
    {
        "jobID": "202012101329yXHTXvqg",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:26",
        "jobEnd": "13:31:58"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "2020121013290Yyjny8x",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:58",
        "jobEnd": "13:30:36"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:28:09",
        "jobEnd": "09:28:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120927afObyUv8",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:27:42",
        "jobEnd": "09:27:58"
    }
];
//first sort it by jobDate
arr.sort(function(item1,item2){
return (new Date(item2.jobDate) - new Date(item1.jobEnd));
});
//then by jobEnd
arr.sort(function(item1,item2){

return (new Date(item2.jobEnd) - new Date(item1.jobEnd));
});
```

I think this will help

Comment: 1.  `"12-10-2020"` is an non-standard date format, so `new Date("12-10-2020")` will be implementation dependant. 2. same for `new Date("13:30:36")` but it's even more likely to  produce an invalid date objects. 3. Two sorts just mean that the data will be sorted by the second criteria, not by both.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for correcting will keep this sceanarios in mind :-)

Comment: unfortunately this solution is not good because it sorts the array by date first (and it's ok) but then sorts the whole array again by the time (and ruins the previous sort).

Answer (score -1):

It was confirmed that it works well in terms of functionality, and it was developed intuitively.

- using `sort()`
  The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.
- with `compareFunction`
  If compareFunction is not supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in UTF-16 code units order. For example, "banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in the Unicode order. All undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array.

reference : [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let data=[
    {
        "jobID": "202012101329yXHTXvqg",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:26",
        "jobEnd": "13:31:58"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "2020121013290Yyjny8x",
        "jobDate": "12-10-2020",
        "jobStart": "13:29:58",
        "jobEnd": "13:30:36"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120928w28NDLQVu",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:28:09",
        "jobEnd": "09:28:25"
    },
    {
        "jobID": "202011120927afObyUv8",
        "jobDate": "12-11-2020",
        "jobStart": "09:27:42",
        "jobEnd": "09:27:58"
    }
]

const compareJobDateThenEndTime = ((a, b) => {
    return (new Date(b.jobDate) - new Date(a.jobDate)) || b.jobEnd.localeCompare(a.jobEnd);
})

let result = data.sort(compareJobDateThenEndTime);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very clean and it works too, thank you.