# Sorting array of objects based on two attributes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to sort Below array based on `name` and `is_closed`.

```
this.rawDataListDup = [
    {id: 1, name: 'john','is_closed':true},
    {id: 2, name: 'james','is_closed':true},
    {id: 3, name: 'jane','is_closed':false},
    {id: 4, name: 'alex','is_closed':false},
    {id: 5, name: 'david','is_closed':true},
];
```

As of now i can only sort using any one of the attribute using below code.

```
let colName = 'name'
this.rawDataListDup.sort((b, a) => a[colName] < b[colName] ? 1 : a[colName] > b[colName] ? -1 : 0)
```

I want array objects with `is_closed = false` on top of array and also it should be in `Alphabetical order`. like this

```
this.rawDataListDup = [
    {id: 4, name: 'alex','is_closed':false},
    {id: 3, name: 'jane','is_closed':false},
    {id: 5, name: 'david','is_closed':true},
    {id: 2, name: 'james','is_closed':true},
    {id: 1, name: 'john','is_closed':true},
];
```

how to do this?

Comment: `rawDataListDup.sort((a,b)=>(a.is_closed-b.is_closed) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `sort` with multiple conditions inside sort:

```js
const rawDataListDup = [
    {id: 1, name: 'john','is_closed':true},
    {id: 2, name: 'james','is_closed':true},
    {id: 3, name: 'jane','is_closed':false},
    {id: 4, name: 'alex','is_closed':false},
    {id: 5, name: 'david','is_closed':true},
];

const sortedList = rawDataListDup.sort((a,b)=>(a.is_closed-b.is_closed) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

console.log(sortedList);
```

Comment: @TheBombSquad That's because types are converted. It's the same as `Number(true) - Number(false)` which are 1 and 0 respectively

Answer (score 0):

It just write simple code.

```
const rawDataListDup = [
    {id: 1, name: 'john','is_closed':true},
    {id: 2, name: 'james','is_closed':true},
    {id: 3, name: 'jane','is_closed':false},
    {id: 4, name: 'alex','is_closed':false},
    {id: 5, name: 'david','is_closed':true},
];

rawDataListDup.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.is_closed - b.is_closed  ||  a.name - b.name;
});
//OR 
    var obj = rawDataListDup.sort((a, b) => a.is_closed - b.is_closed || a.name - b.name);
```

Comment: `a.name - b.name` will result in `NaN`, so the names won't be sorted correctly.

Comment: Then use ternary operator for that check wither its true or false ;

Answer (score 0):

You could also use lodash (sortBy).

Example:
`_.sortBy(rawDataListDup, ['is_closed', 'name']);`