# Sort the array so that zero values ​are always the last and these values ​must be sorted by name

Tags: javascript, sorting

There is an array:

```
const array = 
[
      { name: 'Skill 3', sortOrder: 3 },
      { name: 'Skill 2', sortOrder: null },
      { name: 'Skill 4', sortOrder: 2 },
      { name: 'Skill 1', sortOrder: null },
      { name: 'Skill 5', sortOrder: 1 },
]
```

I need to sort it so that the elements with null values ​​appear at the bottom of the array and sort them by name.

The code I am tormenting with:

```
sortSkills() {
    this.skills.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.sortOrder === b.sortOrder) {
        return 0;
      } else if (a.sortOrder === null) {
        return 1;
      } else if (b.sortOrder === null) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.sortOrder < b.sortOrder) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.sortOrder > b.sortOrder) {
        return 1;
      }
    });
  }
```

Code that works but has a lot of loops in it

```
const nullValuesArray = [];
const numericValuesArray = [];

   this.skills.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.sortOrder === null) {
        nullValuesArray.push(el);
      } else {
        numericValuesArray.push(el);
      }
    });

    nullValuesArray.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    });

    numericValuesArray.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder;
    });

    this.skills = numericValuesArray.concat(nullValuesArray);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for `null` values, sort by the delta of it first and then by `name`.

```js
const array = [{ name: 'Skill 3', sortOrder: 3 }, { name: 'Skill 2', sortOrder: null }, { name: 'Skill 4', sortOrder: 2 }, { name: 'Skill 1', sortOrder: null }, { name: 'Skill 5', sortOrder: 1 }];

array.sort((a, b) => 
    (a.sortOrder === null) - (b.sortOrder === null) || // move null down
    a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder ||                       // sort by order
    a.name.localeCompare(b.name)                       // sort by name
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```