# order by label in pipe RxJS Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable which I use in html with `async` pipe and I want to sort it by `label` at first, but don't understand how to do it correctly inside pipe. Label could be one of this `'High', 'Medium', 'Low'`, and also there is always first object with empty label, I should leave it on first place as it is, so if I receive array like this:

```
[
  {name: 'ALWAYS FIRST', label: ''},
  {name: 'test1', label: 'High'},
  {name: 'test2', label: 'Low'},
  {name: 'test3', label: 'Medium'},
  {name: 'test4', label: 'High'}, 
  ...
]
```

I need to sort it like this

```
[
  {name: 'ALWAYS FIRST', label: ''},
  {name: 'test1', label: 'High'},
  {name: 'test4', label: 'High'}, 
  {name: 'test3', label: 'Medium'},
  {name: 'test2', label: 'Low'},
  ...
]
```

Here's my code

html

```
<div *ngIf="photos$ | async as photos">
  <div *ngFor="let photo of photos" class="photo-item">
    {{photo.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
photos$: Observable<Photos[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.photos$ = this.store.select(selectPhotos)
    .pipe(
      ?
    );
}
```

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pipe actually to solve that, you could operate on the array itself in the subscribe. Or in `map()` to transform the entire data inside the `pipe()` function.

Here's a quick example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dvs3j2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Inside the pipe you need a map operator which maps the array to it's sorted counterpart.

```
this.photos$ = this.store.select(selectPhotos).pipe(
  map(photosArray => photosArray.sort(/* compareFunction */)),
);
```

However, I highly recommend to not do this in the component after selection from the store. From a experienced point of view I recommend to create another selector to select the photos sorted, so other components can use the very same selector without having to care about the sorting.

```
this.photos$ = this.store.select(selectPhotosSortedByLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Adapt the sort mechanism from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256174/6513921.
2. Use spread assignment to separate the first element from the rest of the array.

```js
photos$: Observable<Photos[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.photos$ = this.store.select(selectPhotos).pipe(
    map(([first, ...rest]) => ([
      first,
      ...rest.sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    ]))
  );
}
```