# How to sort first by a property value then by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

let be this object:

```
{
    type: string,
    date: Date
}
```

I have an array of objects as above and I want to sort it to get first items that have 'Premium' as type and then list all the others, ordered by date.

How to accomplish to this with `sort` method of Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom sort function and add some hard constraints. Could have some minor issues, but shoud be ok for the most part

```js
let obj = [{
    type: 'Premium',
    date: new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')
},
{
    type: 'random',
    date: new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')
},
{
    type: 'Premium',
    date: new Date('1995-12-17T03:22:00')
},
{
    type: 'random',
    date: new Date('1995-12-17T03:21:00')
},
{
    type: 'random',
    date: new Date('1995-12-17T03:20:00')
}]

let obj2 = obj.sort((x, y) => {
    if(x.type == 'Premium')
        return 1
    if(y.type == 'Premium')
        return -1
    if(x.date > y.date)
        return 1
    if(x.date < y.date)
        return -1
    return 0
}).reverse()

console.log(obj2)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `reverse()` to make it working? Shouldn't you write a "reverse" version of the custom function instead?

Comment: The idea of reverse is simple. Basically what I'm doing is give the most importance on the 'Premium' type. If you would call sort without a custom implementation, you would have everything sorted in ascending mode. That's why I used reverse, to keep that ascending mode. You can remove reverse and swap the indexes (1 instead of -1 and viceversa) to get the same result

Comment: I did try to swap indexes, but I doesn't work. I keep using `reverse()`. Thank you.

Comment: well, it does work for me [https://jsfiddle.net/Trillyy/9aj0yxuh/](https://jsfiddle.net/Trillyy/9aj0yxuh/)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thank you ;)