# How to sort array of object by a key if duplicate value is seen then sort them by another key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have problem in order to sort an arry of object by two difrent keys.
I want to sort this arry by price and if multi prices were same then sort them by time. I have some thing like this array:

```
var myArr = [
{"value":5 , "price"=10, "time":3},
{"value":1.5 , "price"=2, "time":2},
{"value":3 , "price"=5, "time":4},
{"value":1 , "price"=2, "time":1}
]
```

and after sort have to be something like this:

```
var myArr = [
{"value":1 , "price"=2, "time":1},
{"value":1.5 , "price"=2, "time":2},
{"value":3 , "price"=5, "time":4},
{"value":5 , "price"=10, "time":3}
]
```

I had tried many ways but I can't solve it since it's related to two keys at the same time.

Comment: *i had tried many ways* Great, then add the code that you have tried...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to first sort by `price`, then `time`:

```js
var myArr=[{value:5,price:10,time:3},{value:1.5,price:2,time:2},{value:3,price:5,time:4},{value:1,price:2,time:1}];

myArr.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.price - b.price || a.time - b.time;
});
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Isn't the result is in reverse order?

Comment: This should be `const result = myArr.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price || a.time - b.time)`

Comment: You should first mark it duplicate if it is duplicate...