# How to sort a list with two conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a array that I'm moving a selected element to the top(like it's pinned), now I want to move it back where it was before in the list which I compare the IDs,
so want to show the pinned elements (that does have a key `pinned:true`) to the top of array, and the ones that does not a key `pinned: true` will be sorted by id.

All goes as desired, except when i want to show them as sorted by id which smaller ids will go to the top and greater will go after (1,2,3,4...)

Here is a sandbox where you can get a good idea of what's going on

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-brattain-cro18?file=/src/App.tsx

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Josef", id: 1 },
  { name: "Ali", id: 2 },
  { name: "Sheyda", id: 3 },
  { name: "Parviz", id: 4 },
  { name: "Victor", id: 5 },
  { name: "Mike", id: 6 },
  { name: "Ross", id: 7 },
  { name: "Chandler", id: 8 },
  { name: "Monica", id: 9 }
];
   data.sort(function (x,y) {
      return x.pinned === y.pinned ? 0 : x.pinned ? -1 : 1;
  });
   console.log(data)
```

**So the point is** I want the items with key `pinned:true` **to be at the first**(which item get `true` when i click on it and when I click back it gets false, and by default it's undefined) and **the other** with key pinned set to `false` and `undefined` will go under them and **will be sorted by ids**

**Currently i am able to sort them as `pinned:true` to the top and the other under them but I cannot sort the ones with false by IDs**

Comment: You should post your code in a code block here. Also if you could produce a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. just example input and a few lines of JS (your sorter), that helps a lot for people that want to answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're sorting **just** by whether one element is pinned while the other is not.

In your case, you basically want something like this:

```js
// [value: number, pinned: boolean][]
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    data.push([Math.random() * 100, Math.random() < 0.5]);
}

data.sort((a, b) => {
    const [aValue, aPinned] = a;
    const [bValue, bPinned] = b;
    if (aPinned !== bPinned) return  aPinned ? -1 : 1;
    return aValue - bValue;
});

console.log(data.map(([val, pinned]) => `${pinned ? '[!] ' : ''} ${val}`).join('\n'));
```