# Sort array of objects based first on a subarray and then on dates (without splitting the array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that I want to sort based on whether or not they include a string.

I then want to sort those that do match the string by chronological order, and then the rest by chronological order.

So that

```js
const role = waiter
```

```js
const jobs = [
{ 
"date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
"role": [chef, porter]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-28T00:00:00",
"role": [waiter, chef]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
"role": [waiter, chef]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00",
"role": [chef]
},
]
```

Should become:

```js
[
{ 
"date": "2021-09-28T00:00:00",
"role": [waiter, chef]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
"role": [waiter, chef]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00",
"role": [chef]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
"role": [chef, porter]
},
]
```

So far the only solution I can find is to separate the array into two separate arrays. Sort them individually and then merge them back into one.

My current solution:

```
 const arrOne = jobs
    .filter((j) => j.role.includes(role))
    .sort((a, b) =>
      compareDesc(
        a.date,b.date
      )
    );

 const arrTwo = jobs
    .filter((j) => !j.role.includes(role))
    .sort((a, b) =>
      compareDesc(
        a.date,b.date
      )
    );

const finalArr = [...arrOne,...arrTwo]
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Preferably one that doesn't require splitting the arrays into separate arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: @Andreas Updated my question with what I've tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.sort` and put in the sort conditions (if both match role, then by date, if first only, it goes first, it second only, it goes first, if none, then by date):

```js
const chef = 'chef';
const porter = 'porter';
const waiter = 'waiter';

const role = waiter;

const jobs = [
{ 
"date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
"role": [chef, porter]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-28T00:00:00",
"role": [waiter, chef]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
"role": [waiter, chef]
},
{ 
"date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00",
"role": [chef]
}
]


console.log(jobs.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.role.includes(role) && b.role.includes(role)) {
        return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    } else if (a.role.includes(role)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (b.role.includes(role)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
}));
```

Comment: You haven't found a [suitable dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields) to close it as such?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. first filter, then splice. the push found members to front

```
      const role = 'waiter'
      const jobs = [
      { 
      "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
      "role": ['chef', 'porter']
      },
      { 
      "date": "2021-09-28T00:00:00",
      "role": ['waiter', 'chef']
      },
      { 
      "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
      "role": ['waiter', 'chef']
      },
      { 
      "date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00",
      "role": ['chef']
      },
      ]


      const jobFound = jobs.some(job => job.role.includes(role)); // filter the roles that match.
      if (jobFound) {
        const sortedJobs = jobs.filter((job) => job.role.includes(role)); // filter desired data
        sortedJobs.sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date)); // sort by date
        sortedJobs.forEach((job) => jobs.splice(jobs.indexOf(job), 1)); // splice the object that were matched
        jobs.sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date)); // sort our original array
        jobs.unshift(...sortedJobs); // push ordered members to front of array
      }

      console.log(jobs);
```