# sort order should be by date, then alphabetical (so all active at top A-Z, then all inactive at bottom A-Z)

Tags: javascript

[image]
i have to show the list in sorting order with respect to signature date, `if signature date is not past dated and if there is no date for signature date` then it is considered as active record(sort order should be by status, then alphabetical (so all active at top A-Z, then all inactive at bottom A-Z). I have done sorting based on name but not able to push inactive signature dates to the end.
I have attached DEMO as well.

```js
const  employee = [
{
  name: 'jpat',
  signatureDate: '',
  businessType: 12346,
  originalFileName: 'hello.xls',
  agentW9id: 11,
  fileName: 'hello.xls',
  agentCode: 0,
  class: '',
  status: '',
},
{
  name: 'jcar',
  signatureDate: '09/10/2021',
  businessType: 12346,
  originalFileName: 'test.xls',
  agentW9id: 12,
  fileName: 'test.xls',
  agentCode: 0,
  class: '',
  status: '',
},
{
  name: 'Test',
  signatureDate: '09/23/2020',
  businessType: 12346,
  originalFileName: 'test.xls',
  agentW9id: 13,
  fileName: 'test.xls',
  agentCode: 0,
  class: 'inactive',
  status: 'Inactive',
},
{
  name: 'newTest',
  signatureDate: '10/9/2020',
  businessType: 12346,
  originalFileName: 'test.xls',
  agentW9id: 13,
  fileName: 'test.xls',
  agentCode: 0,
  class: 'inactive',
  status: 'Inactive',
},
{
  name: 'abc',
  signatureDate: '10/29/2021',
  businessType: 12346,
  originalFileName: 'test.xls',
  agentW9id: 13,
  fileName: 'test.xls',
  agentCode: 0,
  class: '',
  status: '',
},
{
  name: 'djhfj',
  signatureDate: '',
  businessType: 12346,
  originalFileName: 'test.xls',
  agentW9id: 13,
  fileName: 'test.xls',
  agentCode: 0,
  class: '',
  status: '',
},
  ];
  
console.log(employee.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)));
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-gmwgbj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: @CBroe thanks for response, but no that is not helping me, i need to inactive status to go at bottom and empty status must be sorted with(A-Z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, updated code,

1. break into objects based on status ( active and inactive)
2. Sort each based on name and append back together

Working code below and [Sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-zyoeqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts)

**Reult image** [image]

```js
const employee = [{
    name: 'jpat',
    signatureDate: '',
    businessType: 12346,
    originalFileName: 'hello.xls',
    agentW9id: 11,
    fileName: 'hello.xls',
    agentCode: 0,
    class: '',
    status: '',
  },
  {
    name: 'jcar',
    signatureDate: '09/10/2021',
    businessType: 12346,
    originalFileName: 'test.xls',
    agentW9id: 12,
    fileName: 'test.xls',
    agentCode: 0,
    class: '',
    status: '',
  },
  {
    name: 'Test',
    signatureDate: '09/23/2020',
    businessType: 12346,
    originalFileName: 'test.xls',
    agentW9id: 13,
    fileName: 'test.xls',
    agentCode: 0,
    class: 'inactive',
    status: 'Inactive',
  },
  {
    name: 'newTest',
    signatureDate: '10/9/2020',
    businessType: 12346,
    originalFileName: 'test.xls',
    agentW9id: 13,
    fileName: 'test.xls',
    agentCode: 0,
    class: 'inactive',
    status: 'Inactive',
  },
  {
    name: 'abc',
    signatureDate: '10/29/2021',
    businessType: 12346,
    originalFileName: 'test.xls',
    agentW9id: 13,
    fileName: 'test.xls',
    agentCode: 0,
    class: 'inactive',
    status: 'Inactive',
  },
  {
    name: 'djhfj',
    signatureDate: '',
    businessType: 12346,
    originalFileName: 'test.xls',
    agentW9id: 13,
    fileName: 'test.xls',
    agentCode: 0,
    class: '',
    status: '',
  }
];

var inactive = [],
  active = [];
employee.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.status == 'Inactive')
    inactive.push(item);
  else
    active.push(item);
});



inactive.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
})

active.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
})


var sortedArray = active.concat(inactive);

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, yes i tried but it is not working as expected, even though name abc must come at the top based on empty status or class sorting, that still comes in the middle

Comment: How come? I have updated the code and its coming at top. check and run the snippet. I have named two names as abc for active and inactive both for you to see that they are sorted by class and names

Comment: i am now able to see list of items i have added initially for result. i will paste the image how i am able to see

Comment: i have attached image for the grid it is displaying

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I have updated the answer and  forked your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-zyoeqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for response, but here if that abc is inactive class then that comes at the top, that is wrong as per my requirement

Comment: my requirement is that, we need to display all active things at the top and inactive items at the last or bottom, and with this condition need to show active items sorted at top(A-Z) and inactive items at bottom sorted as (A-Z)

Comment: @Bhrungarajni Cool, updated the code and sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-zyoeqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237271/discussion-between-tushar-and-bhrungarajni).

Comment: Thanks a ton, working great and i have accepted your answer