# Sorting an array of objects by the rate && alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by the rate and alphabetical order.

So I sorted it by rate successfully. BUT THE PROBLEM is when I tried sorting it by alphabetical order, it doesn't work. I have no idea how to sort it again by alphabetical order.

The source code and the result is written at the bottom.

```
// This is the success result that I want to get **(sorted by rate && sorted by alphabetic order)**

{
abcd ( title)
lorem ipsum (comment)
5 (rate) 
},

{
efg 
lorem ipsum 
5 
},

{
bdg
lorem ipsum
3
},

{
def
lorem ipsum
3
},

{
abc
lorem ipsum
1
}
```

Source Code

```
const Reviews = ({ books, initialData }) => {
  const combinedBooks = initialData.concat(books);

  //   sort by rate
  let sorted = combinedBooks.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.score - a.score;
  });

  //   sort by alphabetical order
    let newSorted = sorted.sort(function (a, b) {
      let fa = a.title.toLowerCase(),
        fb = b.title.toLowerCase();

      if (fa < fb) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (fa > fb) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

  return (
    <section style={{ border: "3px solid green" }}>
      <Header title="Book Review Lists" />
      {sorted.map((review) => {
        const { id, title, comment, score } = review;
        return (
          <Review key={id} title={title} comment={comment} score={score} />
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Reviews;
```

//Code Result

```
{
abc
lorem ipsum
1
},

{
abcd
lorem ipsum 
5 
},

{
bdg
lorem ipsum
3
},

{
def
lorem ipsum
3
},

{
efg ( book title) 
lorem ipsum ( book review )
5 (rate) 
},
```

Comment: Maybe you can only sort alphabetically when the rate is the same. Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: `sort()` modifies the array in place, it doesn't return a new array. So when you sort by name, it undoes the sort by score.

Comment: `combinedBooks.sort((a, b) => b.score === a.score ? a.title.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.title.toLowerCase()) : b.score - a.score);`

Comment: @epascarello Thank you so much for your help!! If you don't mind, can you give me some tips or piece of advice how I can manipulate?! the data pretty well like you?? e.g) data structure & algorithm study tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were sorting by rate first, then sorting alphabetically, so you were getting the items in alphabetical order, then by rank if two items have the same alphabetical order.

To sort that alphabetical list by rank, we do this:

```
 let newerSorted = [...newSorted].sort((a, b) => {
    return b.score - a.score;
  });
```

So the list is now sorted by rank & items with the same rank are sorted alphabetically.

Working Example:

```js
const Reviews = ({ books, initialData }) => {
  const combinedBooks = initialData.concat(books);

  //   sort by rate
  let sorted = combinedBooks.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.score - a.score;
  });
  

  //   sort by alphabetical order
    let newSorted = sorted.sort(function (a, b) {
      let fa = a.title.toLowerCase(),
        fb = b.title.toLowerCase();

      if (fa < fb) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (fa > fb) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    
    let newerSorted = [...newSorted].sort((a, b) => {
    return b.score - a.score;
  });

    
    const Review = (props) => {
        return(
        <li key={props.key}>{props.title} - {props.score}</li>
        );
    }

  return (
  <div>
    <section style={{ border: "3px solid green" }}>
      <p>Sorted alphabetically, then by rank</p>
      {newSorted.map((review) => {
        const { id, title, comment, score } = review;
        return (
          <Review key={id} title={title} comment={comment} score={score} />
        );
      })}
    </section>
    
    <section style={{ border: "3px solid green" }}>
      <p>Sorted by rank, then alphabetically</p>
      {newerSorted.map((review) => {
        const { id, title, comment, score } = review;
        return (
          <Review key={id} title={title} comment={comment} score={score} />
        );
      })}
    </section>
    </div>
  );
};


let initialData = [
    {
        id: 27641,
        title: "abc",
        comment: "m ipsum",
        score: 1
    },
    {
        id: 121232,
        title: "zdseru",
        comment: 'lorem ipsum',
        score: 5,
    },
{
        id: 121232,
        title: "adseru",
        comment: 'lorem ipsum',
        score: 5,
    },

    {
        id: 41,
        title: "new title",
        comment: "lorem ipsum",
        score: 3
    },

    {
        id: 27641,
        title: "xef",
        comment: "lorem ipsum",
        score: 3
    },
    {
       id: 33542,
        title: "ifg",
    comment: "lorem ipsum ( book review )",
        score: 2
},];

let books = [{
    id: 33542,
    title: "new title",
    comment: "comment",
    score: 1
}];

ReactDOM.render(<Reviews books={books} initialData={initialData}/>, document.getElementById('sort'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="sort"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed solution! It works perfectly!!! 
I need to dig into the code to fully understand how it wokrs!!
Thx again for your help!!!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept the answer so that others can also benefit in case of a similar issue. I always appreciate upvotes too ;)

Comment: Sure~!! I just accepted your answer and upvoted too. Thx again :)