# Is there a better way to sort a 2D array twice based on 2 different criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an array: `arr = [[3,2],[1,2],[2,1]]` and I'd like to sort it to: `arr = [[1,2],[3,2],[2,1]]`.
What I am doing is sorting by `subArr[1]` first then in case two elements have equal `subArr[1]`, then sort only those two elements by their `subArr[0]`.

Here is what I did, which I think is stupid for invoking the `.sort()` method twice.

```
function sortArr(array) {
  let arr = array;
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return b[1] - a[1];
  });
  arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a[1] == b[1]) {
      return a[0] - b[0];
    }
    return b[1] - a[1];
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: or [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: Why do you think you even need the first `sort()`? Doesn't using the second one only give you the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one `sort`:

```js
const arr = [[3,2],[1,2],[2,1]];

arr.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1] || a[0] - b[0]);

console.log(arr);
```