# Button on click not triggering my function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this project in which I have to sort all the Id and time with a respective button for each of them.

```
    {
      Id: 1,
      Time: "2022-01-18T14:52:48Z",
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
     Time: "2022-01-18T15:05:28Z",
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Time: "2022-01-18T16:57:58Z",
    },
    {
      Id: 0,
     Time: "2022-01-18T16:00:28Z",
    },
  ];
```

This is the sorting function that I came up with :

```
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.Id - b.Id;
      });
    
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.Time - b.Time;
    });
```

The problems that I am having is that my button on Click does not trigger data.sort function and I am not able to sort Id and Time at the same time. Any idea?

Comment: If this is for React, can you show the whole code within the component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: "The problems that I am having is that my button on Click" — What button?

Comment: the button that i have on my return

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: "the button that i have on my return" doesn't answer the question. You need to show the code where the buttons are defined and set up.

Comment: Did you try to convert the time string into an actual date object before comparison?

Answer (score 1):

To trigger any function by clicking in javascript you have to make your function, like:

```
const dataSorting = () => {

    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.Id - b.Id;
    });

}
```

And then assign it to your button, for example using `addEventListener` [MDN Refrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)