# How can i sort array of objects based on numbers and spefific letters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

i have this array

```
let arr = [
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "abc mo sa 3 Y",
        "mapEventValue": "Y"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "abc a 3 G",
        "mapEventValue": "G"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "cba d 3 S f",
        "mapEventValue": "S"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "cba z 3 R",
        "mapEventValue": "R"
    }
]
```

i need to sort the array FIRST based on the `time` value and after that if the time values are equal i need to sort them based on mapEventValue
in following order `G Y R S`

So in my case all objects are having equal time values `3` I can't find a way to sort them by the `mapEventValue` property

*what i tried*

Until now i just managed to sort them by time value

let sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => a.time - b.time)

So my output at the end should be

```
let arr = [
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "abc a 3 G",
        "mapEventValue": "G"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "abc mo sa 3 Y",
        "mapEventValue": "Y"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "cba z 3 R",
        "mapEventValue": "R"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "cba d 3 S f",
        "mapEventValue": "S"
    },
]
```

Comment: So check if `a.time == b.time` first, and if so, provide a return value based on your second sorting criterion instead ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So only sort by `time` if `time` differs, otherwise sort by the index of your desired sort order.

```js
let sortOrder = 'GYRS';
let arr = [
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "abc mo sa 3 Y",
        "mapEventValue": "Y"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "abc a 3 G",
        "mapEventValue": "G"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "cba d 3 S f",
        "mapEventValue": "S"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "wholeObj": "cba z 3 R",
        "mapEventValue": "R"
    }
];

let sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a.time != b.time) {
    return a.time - b.time;
  } else {
    return sortOrder.indexOf(a.mapEventValue) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.mapEventValue);
  }
});
console.log(sorted);
```