# Javascript: How to rearrange array of objects based on conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, rxjs, javascript-objects

I implemented sort in alphabetical order and wanted rearrange the objects (move all **status red** object to the bottom of the array. How I can move all **status red** data to end of the array in from my onLoad function?

```
// sample data
const data = [
  {
    status: "green",
    name: "alex"
  },
  {
    status: "red",
    name: "ken"
  },
  {
    status: "red",
    name: "roy"
  },
  {
    status: "green",
    name: "boy"
  }
]

users: User[];

// get list
onLoad() {
    this.service.getList$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
        .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
            this.users = users;
                .sort((a, b) => 0 - (a.name > b.name ? -1 : 1));
        });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: Your IDE should mark you some syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Sorting in alphabetical order working, I wanted to implement another operation that move all status `red` to bottom of the list (array).

Comment: First, your code can't work. It contains syntax errors. Second, add a sort function that returns `-1` if only the first argument contains `'red'`, `1` if only the second argument contains `'red'` and otherwise `a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1`

Comment: Do u have any example of that? I don't get it

Comment: `if (a.status === 'red' && b.status !== 'red') return 1; if (a.status !== 'red' && b.status === 'red') return -1; return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: Nice! Thanks @jabaa