# Sort by Date and OrderBy external Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Array of Objects like this:

```
[{
  date: 2022-04-07T01:00:00.000+00:00,
  type: 'profit'
  amount: 200
},{
  date: 2022-04-07T01:00:00.000+00:00,
  type: 'withdraw'
  amount: 600
},{
  date: 2022-04-07T01:00:00.000+00:00,
  type: 'invest'
  amount: 900
},{
  date: 2022-04-08T01:00:00.000+00:00,
  type: 'deposit'
  amount: 200
},{
  date: 2022-04-08T01:00:00.000+00:00,
  type: 'profit'
  amount: 200
}]
```

In the datasource the dates are not in order so I am sorting by date like this:

```
this.allTransactions.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
  return new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime();
});
```

However I need to also sort any objects with the same date by an external array:

```
['invest', 'withdraw', 'profit']
```

I'm struggling with the second part sorting the date groups already sorted by the order in the array. `this.allTransactions` is in an `*ngFor` loop in Angular 12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra condition after your current one, which will be used if the first one resolves as 0

```
const typeOrder = ['invest', 'withdraw', 'profit']

transactions.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime() || typeOrder.indexOf(a.type) - typeOrder.indexOf(b.type)
});
```

Comment: I have seen this on other posts. Unfortunately my returned array of objects seems to ignore the second argument. It's possibly an issue with my date formats. Appreciate your rapid response.

Comment: cracked it by switching the order of the object being sorted:

this.types.indexOf(b.type) - this.types.indexOf(a.type)

Thanks for your help!