# jQuery sorting by two values is not working and only sorts by first value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this

```
['NAME', 5, '2. Defender', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined']
['NAME', 5, '4. Forward', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined']
['NAME', 5, '2. Defender', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined']
['NAME', 4, '4. Forward', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined']
['NAME', 3, '5. Midfielder', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'undefined']
```

I am referencing [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields) on how to sort it, and this is what I have:

```
array.sort(
    function(a, b) {          
      if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        // Price is only important when cities are the same
        return b[2] - a[2];
      }
      return a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : -1;
  });
```

It only sorts by the `[1]` value and will not sort by the secondary `[2]` value. I thought there might be something wrong with my array, but when I switch things to sort by `[2]` first, then it sorts by that value fine. Though the goal is to sort by `[1]` first, and then secondarily sort by `[2]`.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag?

Comment: Because I am writing it in jquery and must have been mistaken if this is pure javascript. (edited the post)

Comment: *Why the downvote?* - you *could* have included a working code snippet that shows the issue. You *must* also provide debugging details. And your "array" is not an array. Thanks to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I appreciate your time and like I said I did my best. Thankfully, @oyophant below provided the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third array element [2] is a string which you can't compare by subtraction. Use `.localeCompare` instead

```
array.sort((a, b) => a[1] !== b[1] ? a[1] - b[1] : a[2].localeCompare(b[2]))
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time. Would there be a way to add a third value to sort by if I were to use [3]?

Comment: You're welcome - of course you can always append more comparisons like `a[1] !== b[1] ? a[1]-b[1] : (a[2].localeCompare(b[2])!==0 ? a[2].localeCompare(b[2]) : a[3].localeCompare(b[3]))`

Comment: Could I bother you to see an example adding in the [3] value? I have not been able to find that and would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you so much again. Stack Overflow can be a daunting place and I appreciate your knowledge, kindness, and time.

Comment: just edited the answer above

Comment: Using `localeCompare` with for example `1. Defender, 2. Defender, 10. Defender` will get you `1 > 10 > 2`. Be warned.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - if you have the string beginning with numbers larger than 9 and you want them sorted by the numerical value then you should do a numerical conversion before

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a mathematical operation with two strings (`'2. Defender'` vs. `'4. Forward'`).
You can just **nest** the same comparison you make for `a[1]` vs. `b[1]` as below:

```js
let array = [
  ['ONE1', 5, '2. Defender', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['TWO2', 5, '4. Forward', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['THR3', 5, '2. Defender', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['FOR4', 4, '4. Forward', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['FIV5', 3, '5. Midfielder', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'undefined']
]
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a[1] === b[1]) {
    // Price is only important when cities are the same
    if (a[2] === b[2]) {
      //return 0;
      /* 
        or nest another comparison here and as many times as needed 
        within each child `a[n]===b[n]` block
       */
      if (a[3] === b[3]) {
        return 0; // or compare yet another col
      }
      return a[3] < b[3] ? 1 : -1;
    }

    return a[2] < b[2] ? 1 : -1;
  }

  return a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : -1;
})

array.forEach((p) => {
  console.log(p[0])
})
```

Otherwise you need to get the integer value of those strings to be able to do the math. You can use `parseInt()` or assign an explicit value according to your logic for each sorting column as below:

```js
let array = [
  ['ONE1', 5, '2. Defender', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['TWO2', 5, '4. Forward', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['THR3', 5, '2. Defender', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['FOR4', 4, '4. Forward', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'undefined'],
  ['FIV5', 3, '5. Midfielder', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'undefined']
]
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a[1] === b[1]) {
    // Price is only important when cities are the same
    let c = parseInt(a[2]);
    let d = parseInt(b[2]);
    if (c === d) {
      // the string 'TRUE' before 'FALSE', '' or null 
      let e = (a[3] === 'TRUE') ? 1 : 0;
      let f = (b[3] === 'TRUE') ? 1 : 0;

      return f - e;
    }

    return d - c;
  }

  return a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : -1;
})

array.forEach((p) => {
  console.log(...p)
})
```